# Better to install underscore via NPM or Bower?

Tags: node.js, installation, underscore.js, npm, bower

I'm building a NodeJS app and using UnderscoreJS. Would it be more applicable as a Bower or NPM installation? Is there actually any difference? I'm using it on front and back-end. What's the proper way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's already answered here : [What is the difference between Bower and npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641899/difference-between-bower-and-npm)

So, Here is the answer:

> npm is most commonly used for managing Node.js modules, but it works
>   for the front-end too when combined with Browserify and/or $ npm
>   dedupe.
>
> Bower is created solely for the front-end and is optimized with that
>   in mind. The biggest difference is that npm does nested dependency
>   tree (size heavy) while Bower requires a flat dependency tree (puts
>   the burden of dependency resolution on the user).
>
> A nested dependency tree means that your dependencies can have its own
>   dependencies which can have their own, and so on. This is really great
>   on the server where you don't have to care much about space and
>   latency. It lets you not have to care about dependency conflicts as
>   all your dependencies use e.g. their own version of Underscore. This
>   obviously doesn't work that well on the front-end. Imagine a site
>   having to download three copies of jQuery.
>
> The reason many projects use both is that they use Bower for front-end
>   packages and npm for developer tools like Yeoman, Grunt, Gulp, JSHint,
>   CoffeeScript, etc.
>
> All package managers have many downsides. You just have to pick which
>   you can live with.

Answer (score 0):

Using Bower is better. This allows you to automatically keep your dependencies up to date, **plus** you can add them to index automatically with grunt.

```
bower install underscore; grunt bowerInstall;
```

Comment: gulp implementation of the above?