# Would bower only be useful for css if using browserify and node.js commonJs

Tags: node.js, bower, browserify, commonjs

I see from this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641899/difference-between-bower-and-npm) the difference between bower and npm:

**npm** is used for managing Node.js modules, but can work on the front-end too when combined with Browserify or WebPack. npm does nested dependency tree, so your dependencies can have their own dependencies which can have their own... which basically can mean a lot of versions of the same modules together, but not a problem on the server, and Browserify handles this by only bundling the appropriate modules.

**Bower** is used for the front-end only and is optimized with that in mind. It requires a flat dependency tree, putting the burden of dependency resolution on the user, which makes sense on the client as we want to minimize the number of includes,

**My question:**

***If we are using Browserify, Is there much point to using bower for managing front end dependencies, other than the following 2 benefits?***

- managing front end css modules includes, e.g. pure.css or bootstrap.css,
- including 1 or 2 large JavaScript libraries e.g. Angular, React or jQuery as a global version on the page separate to your Browserify bundle - *would that be a benefit to reduce bloat from your bundle.js, even if it means an additional http request*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also get the 2 benefits you mention using npm:

- Bootstrap and PureCSS are available as npm packages
- You can install large libraries with npm and create separate bundles for them using Browserify

This is also a debate we are having in my company and I am starting to opt for a npm-only approach.

More on this:

- http://blog.npmjs.org/post/101775448305/npm-and-front-end-packaging
- http://dontkry.com/posts/code/using-npm-on-the-client-side.html