# How to use jQuery with Angular?

Tags: jquery, angular

Can anyone tell me, how to use **jQuery** with **Angular**?

```
class MyComponent {
    constructor() {
        // how to query the DOM element from here?
    }
}
```

I'm aware there are workarounds like manipulating the *class* or *id* of the DOM element upfront, but I'm hoping for a cleaner way of doing it.

Comment: Don't know which version you were using at the time you posted but to me adding JQuery cdn in index.html is enough to call $ in a component

Comment: It might help http://www.code-sample.com/2016/07/use-jquery-with-angular-2.html

Comment: please refer below link to use Jquery in Angular 2- http://stackoverflow.com/a/42044459/1089766

Comment: Just follow these simple steps here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42295505/7532440

Comment: While some jQuery functionality (especially plugins or jQueryUI) can be very useful in an Angular2 app, it is not best practice to query and manipulate the DOM from inside Angular2 components, as you described in your question. In Angular2 apps the DOM elements you want to manipulate should be bound to your component model. DOM elements state should change according to model changes. Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42411744/best-practice-of-angular-2

Comment: If you are looking to query DOM elements, you should try Angular Renderer2 instead of jQuery. https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2

Comment: I think the correct answer for this is: You Dont. Angular is more advanced and newer than jquery, its not outdated and has a lot cleaner code

Comment: Why should a person use JQuery with Angular?

Comment: @Cristian Tralna What if someone wants to use existing jQuery based libraries in angular application? Though I understand that Angular and Jquery are 2 different world from architectural point of view but lets say someone have lots of functionality (or few lines of code which is very importent) coded in jquery based libraries,  He/She might needed to use jquery $ along with typescript.

Comment: You can read my blog post here https://ngohungphuc.wordpress.com/2019/02/07/using-jquery-with-angular/

Comment: When you use Angular, try not to use the jquery library.
Try using the features and the libraries that are produced for angular framework.
If you want to use the jquery functions like **find()**, **html()**, **closest()** and etc.., I suggest using the pure js. example: **querySelector()**, **innerHTML**, **parentElement** and etc...

Comment: you can use ElementRef instead, just look angular documentation

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I've heard this said over and over, and starting to think it's just groupthink. I see things tout "jquery free" and think it's just a personal goal or something, the user doesn't know or care, and whether they say it or not, Google isn't really going to get rid of nativeelement. Bootstrap modal is really the only place I tend to use it, but it just seems like there's a cult against it "just because". Plus, it's really not that hard to refactor out if it ever needs to go, provided there's not a better way to do things.

Answer (score 363, accepted):

Using jQuery from Angular2 is a breeze compared to ng1. If you are using TypeScript you could first reference jQuery typescript definition.

```
tsd install jquery --save
or
typings install dt~jquery --global --save
```

TypescriptDefinitions are not required since you could just use `any` as the type for `$` or `jQuery`

In your angular component you should reference a DOM element from the template using `@ViewChild()` After the view has been initialized you can use the `nativeElement` property of this object and pass to jQuery.

Declaring `$` (or `jQuery`) as JQueryStatic will give you a typed reference to jQuery.

```
import {bootstrap}    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
declare var $:JQueryStatic;

@Component({
    selector: 'ng-chosen',
    template: `<select #selectElem>
        <option *ngFor="#item of items" [value]="item" [selected]="item === selectedValue">{{item}} option</option>
        </select>
        <h4> {{selectedValue}}</h4>`
})
export class NgChosenComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('selectElem') el:ElementRef;
    items = ['First', 'Second', 'Third'];
    selectedValue = 'Second';

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        $(this.el.nativeElement)
            .chosen()
            .on('change', (e, args) => {
                this.selectedValue = args.selected;
            });
    }
}

bootstrap(NgChosenComponent);
```

This example is available on plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Nq9LnK?p=preview

tslint will complain about `chosen` not being a property on $, to fix this you can add a definition to the JQuery interface in your custom *.d.ts file

```
interface JQuery {
    chosen(options?:any):JQuery;
}
```

Comment: It works! thx. Unfortunately the doc of `ElementRef.domElement` states *(DEPRECATED way of accessing the DOM, replacement coming)*. Also the `setTimeout` seems like a workaround. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: I'm not sure why the `setTimeout` workaround is required. I have tried with several other jQuery components, and it seems like all of them require this workaround for correct initialization. I hope this will change in future release of ng2

Comment: Because while construction there is only some *Phantom DOM Element* instead of the final element. The actual Element is only available after the constructor is finished.

Comment: I have some issues while using jquery plugins with angular 2 router (dropzone , chosen ... ) . When a component is loaded in the outlet the constructor is called and the template is processed ... the jquery plugin ( with the setTimout hack ) can be initialised .. but when you load another component ( with the router ) and you come back to the first component .. Angular2 recycle the view ( despite that it recalls the constructor ) .. so the elements constructed by Angular plugins in the first time are shown again :(

Comment: new callbacks have been added in alpha37

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.37/CHANGELOG.md

core: added afterContentInit, afterViewInit, and afterViewChecked hooks (d49bc43), closes #3897

Comment: @MouradZouabi: For those of us that are new to this, could you explain the significance of your comment? An additional answer would really be awesome! (thx if so!!)

Comment: You can implement the lifecycle hook **afterViewInit()** to add some DOM manipulations

afterViewInit() {
            var el:any = elelemtRef.domElement.children[0];
            $(el).chosen().on('change', (e, args) => {
                _this.selectedValue = args.selected;
            });
}

Be careful when using router because angular2 may recycle view .. so you have to be sure that the DOM elements manipulations are done only in the first call of afterViewInit .. ( You can use static boolean variables to do so )

Comment: Have you tryed using this with data that comes from a http request? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me a lot! Thought I'm using `typings` now, what about updating your comment with `typings` instead of `tsd`? I was thinking it could help others :)

Comment: this isn't that difficult to set up, but it's certainly not "a breeze" compared to angular 1. in angular 1 you didn't have to do anything, and you could just use jquery anywhere. angular 1 is built on top of jquery.

Comment: After installing definitions though typings, JQueryStatic is still not recognized.

Comment: I have same issue as Gonzalo

Comment: I think we need to update this a bit as now we use NPM for typings

Comment: `npm install @types/jquery --save`

Comment: Note that if your element in the template is within an *ngIf, the ElementRef returns undefined. Use [hidden] instead

Comment: In the npm docs, it says you should be able to do `import $ from "jquery"` should that work? (It doesn't appear to) - https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery

Comment: Better use Renderer2 class to manipulate the dom. https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2

Comment: after installing jquery via nmp, import it like this `declare var $:any;` or `import $ from "jquery"; `

Answer (score 160):

This is what worked for me.

### STEP 1 - First things first

```
// In the console
// First install jQuery
npm install --save jquery
// and jQuery Definition
npm install -D @types/jquery
```

### STEP 2 - IMPORT

```
// Now, within any of the app files (ES2015 style)
import * as $ from 'jquery';
//
$('#elemId').width();

// OR

// CommonJS style - working with "require"
import $ = require('jquery')
//
$('#elemId').width();
```

### #UPDATE - `Feb - 2017`

Lately, I'm writing code with `ES6` instead of `typescript` and am able to `import` without `* as $` in the `import statement`.   This is what it looks like now:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
//
$('#elemId').width();
```

Good Luck.

Comment: what is npm install -D @types/jquery in backquotes supposed to mean?

Comment: @Toolkit, I fixed the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Took me an hour to figure out how to put jQuery into Angular 2 (Properly)... Pretty sure web development is going backwards.

Comment: In order to import $ from 'jquery' work you need to set --allowJs

Comment: `import * as $ from 'jquery';` in **app.module.ts** to make it available to the whole project.
And btw: ["Why --save instead of --save-dev?"](https://github.com/Microsoft/types-publisher/issues/81)

Comment: `import $ from 'jquery';` That's the prettiest jquery import statement on this page imo. Exactly what I would want it to look like.

Comment: @Starboy that is because you shouldn't need any JQuery in an Angular application and if you do, you are most probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Also note that adding  the "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true compiler option in your tsconfig.json file might be needed to avoid any error.

Comment: What exactly does that -D flag do?

Comment: Hi @Willie,  `-D` a shorthand flag for `--save-dev`.  This will install the pacakge under `devDependencies` instead of `dependencies`.

Comment: I think this is what everyone is looking for :)

Comment: @phil294 agreed with you.

Answer (score 128):

Why is everyone making it a rocket science?
For anyone else who needs to do some basic stuff on static elements, for example, `body` tag, just do this:

1. In index.html add `script` tag with the path to your jquery lib, doesn't matter where (this way you can also use IE conditional tags to load lower version of jquery for IE9 and less).
2. In your `export component` block have a function that calls your code: `$("body").addClass("done");` Normaly this causes declaration error, so just after all imports in this .ts file, add `declare var $:any;` and you are good to go!

Comment: Hahaha just jump to your ans and it work thanks :) ;)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. So I am gonna be studying some rocket science. :)

Comment: Dude, hands down best answer! Not complicated and worked first try.

Comment: The point of angular 2 is to remove the complexity of dealing with the DOM. Angular 2 has a diff algorithm that will efficiently render your components for you, that's why its better to trick jquery that its manipulating the DOM by pointing it to the angular 2 component, instead of directly manipulating the DOM.

Comment: intellisense, my friend, that is why

Comment: No doubt it sounded like rocket science before i read your post. Thanks :)

Comment: `declare var $:any;` for the win!

Comment: This definitely works, but if you're not living in the stone age anymore, go with the accepted answer instead.

Comment: Great answer !! Don't forget that this is web, we will be dealing with DOM forever

Comment: @Starwave In angular 4 I used some click event using jquery. All are working fine. But the click events not triggered inside the .subscribe(jsonData => {}... i.e inside the subscribe method. Any ideas in it??

Answer (score 59):

Now it has become very easy, You can do it by simply declaring jQuery variable with any type inside Angular2 controller.

```
declare var jQuery:any;
```

Add this just after import statements and before component decorator.

To access any element with id X or Class X you just have to do

```
jQuery("#X or .X").someFunc();
```

Comment: Verified, this works for angular 2 with webpack(a SPA template generate by yeoman Aspnetcore SPA). Often the simplest approach works the best! Thanks.

Comment: I am using it on my project but the lack of this method is we are losing all the strong type capability of jQuery types :)

Comment: Working in Angular 6 (6.0.3)

Comment: Working in:
Angular CLI: 7.1.4
Node: 10.15.0

Answer (score 34):

A simple way:

**1. include script**

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

**2. declare**

my.component.ts

```
declare var $: any;
```

**3. use**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
 ...
  $("#myselector").style="display: none;";
}
```

Comment: Worked for me. But instead of implements OnInit (which Angular did not want to accept) I used inside MyComponent ngOnInit() { // my jQuery here }

Answer (score 28):

Please follow these simple steps. It worked for me. Lets start with a new angular 2 app to avoid any confusion. I'm using Angular cli. So, install it if you don't have it already.
https://cli.angular.io/

**Step 1: Create a demo angular 2 app**

```
ng new jquery-demo
```

you can use any name. Now check if it is working by running below cmd.(Now, make sure that you are pointing to 'jquery-demo' if not use cd command )

```
ng serve
```

you will see "app works!" on browser.

**Step 2: Install Bower (A package manager for the web)**

Run this command on cli (make sure that you are pointing to 'jquery-demo' if not use cd command ):

```
npm i -g bower --save
```

Now after successful installation of bower, Create a 'bower.json' file by using below command:

```
bower init
```

It will ask for inputs, just press enter for all if you want default values and at the end type "Yes" when it'll ask "Looks good?"

Now you can see a new file (bower.json) in folder "jquery-demo". You can find more info on https://bower.io/

**Step 3: Install jquery**

Run this command

```
bower install jquery --save
```

It will create a new folder (bower_components) which will contain jquery installation folder. Now you have jquery installed in 'bower_components' folder.

**Step 4: Add jquery location in 'angular-cli.json' file**

Open 'angular-cli.json' file (present in 'jquery-demo' folder) and add jquery location in "scripts". It will look like this:

```
"scripts": ["../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
              ]
```

**Step 5: Write simple jquery code for testing**

Open 'app.component.html' file and add a simple code line, The file will look like this:

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>
<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
```

Now Open 'app.component.ts' file and add jquery variable declaration and code for 'p' tag. You should use lifecycle hook ngAfterViewInit() also. After making changes the file will look like this:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var $:any;

@Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
     title = 'app works!';

     ngAfterViewInit(){
           $(document).ready(function(){
             $("p").click(function(){
             $(this).hide();
             });
           });
     }
}
```

Now run your angular 2 app by using 'ng serve' command and test it. It should work.

Comment: IMHO. This is the best approach I still use bower for client-side dependencies.

Comment: "`$("p").click(function(){ $(this).hide(); });`" best example of when **do not** use jQuery in Angular?!

Comment: Isn't it easier to setup just using npm? `npm install jquery --save`, then `"scripts":["../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"]`, then `import $ from 'jquery';` in *.ts files. What is the advantage using bower?

Comment: @cs_pupil You can use npm too but Bower is designed for managing only front end packages. Have a lookup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641899/what-is-the-difference-between-bower-and-npm

Comment: @AmanDeepSharma, thanks! Oddly enough though, it looks like bower has been deprecated. `npm install bower` yielded: `npm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.0:` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31219726/3806701)

Answer (score 25):

Using Angular Cli

```
 npm install jquery --save
```

In angular.json under scripts array

```
"scripts": [ "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ] // copy relative path of node_modules>jquery>dist>jquery.min.js to avoid path error
```

Now to use jQuery, all you have to do is to import it as follows in whatever component you want to use jQuery.

For example importing and using jQuery in root component

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery'; // I faced issue in using jquery's popover
Or
declare var $: any; // declaring jquery in this way solved the problem

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {


ngOnInit() {
}

jQueryExampleModal() { // to show a modal with dummyId
   $('#dummyId').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: path is wrong use./node_modules instead of ../node_modules

Comment: you can also install `@types/jquery` using the command: `npm i --save-dev @types/jquery` and add `"types": ["jquery"]` to the file `tsconfig.app.json` or `tsconfig.lib.json` under `compilerOptions` and this way ommit the `declare var $: any;` statement altogether

Answer (score 13):

You can implement the lifecycle hook **ngAfterViewInit()** to add some DOM manipulations

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
            var el:any = elelemtRef.domElement.children[0];
            $(el).chosen().on('change', (e, args) => {
                _this.selectedValue = args.selected;
            });
}
```

Be careful when using router because angular2 may recycle views .. so you have to be sure that the DOM elements manipulations are done only in the first call of afterViewInit .. ( You can use static boolean variables to do so )

```
class Component {
    let static chosenInitialized  : boolean = false;
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        if (!Component.chosenInitialized) {
            var el:any = elelemtRef.domElement.children[0];
            $(el).chosen().on('change', (e, args) => {
                _this.selectedValue = args.selected;
            });
            Component.chosenInitialized = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Property 'domElement' does not exist on type ElementRef`

Answer (score 13):

If you use angular-cli you can do :

1. **Install the dependency** :

   npm install jquery --save

   npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
2. **Import the file** :

   Add "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" to the "script" section in .angular-cli.json file
3. **Declare jquery** :

   Add "$" to the "types" section of tsconfig.app.json

You can find more details on [official angular cli doc](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib)

Comment: This causes the following error when building: ERROR in error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '$'.

Comment: error TS1192: Module ''jquery'' has no default export

Answer (score 13):

step 1: use the command : npm install jquery --save

step 2: you can simply import angular as :

import $ from 'jquery';

that's all .

An example would be :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import  $ from 'jquery';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  constructor(){
    console.log($('body'));
  }


}
```

Comment: Module ..node_modules/@types/jquery/index"' has no default export

Answer (score 12):

I do it in simpler way - first install jquery by npm in console: `npm install jquery -S` and then in component file I just write: `let $ = require('.../jquery.min.js')` and it works! Here full example from some my code:

```
import { Component, Input, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
let $ = require('../../../../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');

@Component({
    selector: 'departments-connections-graph',
    templateUrl: './departmentsConnectionsGraph.template.html',
})

export class DepartmentsConnectionsGraph implements OnInit {
    rootNode : any;
    container: any;

    constructor(rootNode: ElementRef) {
      this.rootNode = rootNode; 
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.container = $(this.rootNode.nativeElement).find('.departments-connections-graph')[0];
      console.log({ container : this.container});
      ...
    }
}
```

In teplate I have for instance:

```
<div class="departments-connections-graph">something...</div>
```

---

**EDIT**

Alternatively instead of using:

```
let $ = require('../../../../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');
```

use

```
declare var $: any;
```

and in your index.html put:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
```

This will initialize jquery only once globaly - this is important for instance for use modal windows in bootstrap...

Comment: i don't know I never use angular-cli but I use angular2-webpack-starter and it works there.

Comment: where is that require method come from?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603514/javascript-require-function-giving-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined

Comment: You have a typo => `console.log({ conatiner : this.container});` fix it to `console.log({ container: this.container}); `

Answer (score 10):

//installing jquery`npm install jquery --save`

//installing type defintion for the jquery`typings install dt~jquery --global --save`

//adding jquery library into build configuration file as specified(in "angular-cli-build.js" file)

```
vendorNpmFiles: [
  .........
  .........
  'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
]
```

//run the build to add the jquery library in the build   `ng build`

//adding the relative path configuration(in system-config.js)
 `/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
    const map: any = {
    .....,
    .......,
    'jquery': 'vendor/jquery/dist'
   };`

```
/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
......,
'jquery':{ main: 'jquery.min',
format: 'global',
defaultExtension: 'js'}};
```

//import the jquery library in your component file

```
import 'jquery';
```

below is the code snipppet of my sample component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import 'jquery';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',  
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  list:Array<number> = [90,98,56,90];
  title = 'app works!';
  isNumber:boolean = jQuery.isNumeric(89)  
  constructor(){}
}
```

Comment: Awesome it works perfect for ng-cli projects.. Thanks!

Comment: Super slick! I'm using Angular-cli for my project and this is gold! Rock on

Comment: I have no 'angular-cli-build.js' file :/

Answer (score 9):

To Use Jquery in Angular2(4)

Follow these setps

install the Jquery and Juqry type defination

For Jquery Installation `npm install jquery --save`

For Jquery Type defination Installation  `npm install @types/jquery --save-dev`

and then simply import the jquery

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent { 
  console.log($(window)); // jquery is accessible 
}
```

Comment: dup of [Akash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular2#answer-40355691) !?

Answer (score 7):

First, install jQuery using npm as follows:

```
npm install jquery — save
```

Second, go to the ./angular-cli.json file at the root of your Angular CLI project folder, and find the scripts: [] property, and include the path to jQuery as follows:

```
"scripts": [ "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]
```

Now, to use jQuery, all you have to do is to import it in whatever component you want to use jQuery.

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
(or)
declare var $: any;
```

Take a look at the below code that uses jQuery to animate div on click, especially in the second line. We are importing everything as $ from jQuery.

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Look jQuery Animation working in action!';

  public ngOnInit()
  {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            var div = $("div");  
            div.animate({left: '100px'}, "slow");
            div.animate({fontSize: '5em'}, "slow");
        });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just write

```
declare var $:any;
```

after all import sections, you can use jQuery and include the jQuery library in your index.html page

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

it worked for me

Answer (score 5):

**Angular 12**

`npm i jquery`

this is important : `npm i @types/jquery`

angular.json

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            ]
```

.ts file

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
```

Answer (score 4):

Since I'm a dunce, I thought it would be good to have some working code.

Also, Angular2 typings version of [angular-protractor has issues with the jQuery](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/issues/1126) `$`, so the top accepted answer doesn't give me a clean compile.

Here are the steps that I got to be working:

index.html

```
<head>
...
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
...
</head>
```

Inside my.component.ts

```
import {
    Component,
    EventEmitter,
    Input,
    OnInit,
    Output,
    NgZone,
    AfterContentChecked,
    ElementRef,
    ViewChild
} from "@angular/core";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

declare var jQuery:any;

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'mycomponent',
    templateUrl: 'my.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../../scss/my.component.css'],
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentChecked{
...
    scrollLeft() {

        jQuery('#myElement').animate({scrollLeft: 100}, 500);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I am skipping installation of jquery since this point has been mentioned in all of the posts created prior to mine. So, you have already installed jquery. Importing t into your component like this

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

will work, but there is another 'angular" way to do this by creating a service.

Step no. 1: create **jquery.service.ts file**.

```
// in Angular v2 it is OpaqueToken (I am on Angular v5)
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
export const JQUERY_TOKEN = new InjectionToken('jQuery');
```

Step. no. 2: register the service in **app.module.ts**

```
import { JQUERY_TOKEN } from './services/jQuery.service';
declare const jQuery: Object;

providers: [
    { provide: JQUERY_TOKEN, useValue: jQuery },
]
```

Step no. 3: inject the service into your component **my-super-duper.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';

export class MySuperDuperComponent {
    constructor(@Inject(JQUERY_TOKEN) private $: any) {}

    someEventHandler() {
        this.$('#my-element').css('display', 'none');
    }
}
```

I will be very grateful if somebody can explain pros and cons of both methods: DI jquery as a service vs. import * as $ from 'jquery';

Answer (score 3):

Others already posted. but I give a simple example here so that can help some new comers.

Step-1: In your index.html file reference jquery cdn

```
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Step-2: assume we want to show div or hide div on click of a button:

```
 <input type="button" value="Add New" (click)="ShowForm();">


 <div class="container">
  //-----.HideMe{display:none;} is a css class----//

  <div id="PriceForm" class="HideMe">
     <app-pricedetails></app-pricedetails>
  </div>
  <app-pricemng></app-pricemng>
 </div>
```

Step-3:In the component file bellow the import declare $ as bellow:

```
declare var $: any;
```

than create function like bellow:

```
 ShowForm(){
   $('#PriceForm').removeClass('HideMe');
 }
```

It will work with latest Angular and JQuery

Answer (score 2):

1) To access DOM in component.

```
import {BrowserDomAdapter } from '@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/browser_adapter';
constructor(el: ElementRef,public zone:NgZone) {
     this.el = el.nativeElement;
     this.dom = new BrowserDomAdapter();
 }
 ngOnInit() {
   this.dom.setValue(this.el,"Adding some content from ngOnInit"); 
 }
```

You can include jQuery in following way. 
2) Include you jquery file in index.html before angular2 loads

```
      <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- jquery file -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
```

You can use Jquery in following way, Here i am using JQuery Ui date picker.

```
    import { Directive, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
    declare  var $:any;
    @Directive({
      selector: '[uiDatePicker]',
     })
    export class UiDatePickerDirective {
      private el: HTMLElement;
      constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        this.el = el.nativeElement;

     }

    ngOnInit() {
        $(this.el).datepicker({
         onSelect: function(dateText:string) {
            //do something on select
         }
        });
    }
}
```

This work for me.

Answer (score 2):

**Global Library Installation** as [Official documentation here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-lib#global-library-installation)

1. **Install from npm:**

   **`npm install jquery --save`**
2. **Add needed script files to scripts:**

   **`"scripts": [
     "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js"
   ],`**

Restart server if you're running it, and it should be working on your app.

---

If you want to use inside single component use **`import $ from 'jquery';`** inside your component

Answer (score 1):

The most effective way that I have found is to use setTimeout with time of 0 inside of the page/component constructor. This let's the jQuery run in the next execution cycle after Angular has finished loading all the child components. A few other component methods could be used but all I have tried work best when run inside a setTimeout.

```
export class HomePage {
    constructor() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            // run jQuery stuff here
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should definitely use `ngOnInit()` rather than this

Comment: ngAfterViewInit()

Comment: `setTimeout` not really work actually if you have many items in `*ngFor` to render finish.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is what worked for me - Angular 2 with webpack**

I tried declaring `$` as type `any` but whenever I tried to use any JQuery module I was getting (for example) `$(..).datepicker()` is not a function

Since I have Jquery included in my vendor.ts file I simply imported it into my component using

`import * as $ from 'jquery';`

I am able to use Jquery plugins (like bootstrap-datetimepicker) now

Comment: Note that your app will take 5x longer to bootstrap.

Comment: @jake is it due to the time taken to load bootstrap libraries?

Comment: No, jquery takes longer. bootstrap !== twitter bootstrap

Comment: @jake oops! I meant jquery i guess. Thanks for the note

Comment: @jake would you mind explaining why an app will take 5x longer to bootstrap by making jquery available to the whole application

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to import it with the "InjectionToken". 
As described here: [Use jQuery in Angular/Typescript without a type definition](https://thecodegarden.net/jquery-in-angular-typescript-without-type-definition/)

You can simply inject the jQuery global instance and use it. For this you won't be needing any type definitions or typings.

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const JQ_TOKEN = new InjectionToken('jQuery');

export function jQueryFactory() {
    return window['jQuery'];
}

export const JQUERY_PROVIDER = [
    { provide: JQ_TOKEN, useFactory: jQueryFactory },
];
```

When set correctly in your app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { JQ_TOKEN } from './jQuery.service';

declare let jQuery: Object;

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: JQ_TOKEN, useValue: jQuery }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

You can start using it in your components:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { JQ_TOKEN } from './jQuery.service';

@Component({
    selector: "selector",
    templateUrl: 'somefile.html'
})
export class SomeComponent {
    constructor( @Inject(JQ_TOKEN) private $: any) { }

    somefunction() {
        this.$('...').doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add this code Below in src/Main.ts will important jquery and all function in all project

```
import * as jquery from 'jquery';
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
```

not forget **npm i @types/jquery** and **npm i @types/bootstrap**

Answer (score -1):

Install jquery

Terminal$ `npm install jquery`

(For bootstrap 4...)

Terminal$ `npm install popper.js`

Terminal$ `npm install bootstrap`

Then add the `import` statement to `app.module.ts`.

```
import 'jquery'
```

(For bootstrap 4...)

```
import 'popper.js'
import 'bootstrap'
```

Now you will no longer need `<SCRIPT>` tags to reference the JavaScript.

(Any CSS you want to use still has to be referenced in `styles.css`)

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```