# How to get jquery ui date picker working with angular2?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, typescript, angular

How to get jquery ui date picker working with angular2?

I'm using angular2 and typescript with html5.

I'm trying to add the jquery ui datepicker.

I have all the librarys and the css added but the datepicker jquery code is wiring up to the html.

lib: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

**Heres my code:**

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>

  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

I've tried putting this in my component :  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
But I just get errors.

any ideas?

I get this error when I add the project to mine:

[image]

Comment: I just couldnt get the datepicker work in an angular 2 environment

Comment: it didnt like the $ in the component

Comment: PrimeNG will provide a datepicker very soon according to their roadmap. http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3763

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are already many datepicker libraries available for the angular2. few of them i have posted below:

- https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker
- https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-datepicker
- http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

but yes obviously everyone need stylish datepicker for our project me too want same so i according to need i have created one datepicker using bootflat framework for styling. you can refer here..

https://github.com/MrPardeep/Angular2-DatePicker

hope this may help you !

[image]

Comment: sorry but this referred repo is working fine for me...btw whats the error you have ?

Comment: Which one of the three links above did you try?

Comment: does it work in internet explorer? because the documentation says chrome and firefox

Comment: i have't tested on IE you can test. i am not sure about this

Comment: is there a demo link? so i can try it first in ie?

Comment: nop sorry you have to clone the repo first then only you can use this.

Comment: I've added the error image above. I just tried to add your date picker to my project

Comment: The question asks about the `jQueryUI Datepicker` not for alternatives - Although it maybe helpful to list alternative as an aside, it doesn't answer the question

Comment: @LukeTO'Brien internally this datepicker is using `jQuery` so posting as answer, and i dont think this answer is too bad to be downvote isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

PrimeNG also provides a component for DatePicker. Live demo;

http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

Answer (score 1):

See this question as a answer of how to use `jQuery UI` plugins in your app [Whats the best way to use jquery widgets inside angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600151/whats-the-best-way-to-use-jquery-widgets-inside-angular-2)

This example uses [ElementRef](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html) but you could also use [ViewChild](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html)

:-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one with many configurations, live demo:
https://vlio20.github.io/ng2-date-picker/