# Does anyone know how to get jQuery UI date picker working in an AngularJS 2 app?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, angular

Does anyone know how to get jQuery UI date picker working in an AngularJS 2 app?

I've used jQuery UI date picker before in AngularJS 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get jquery ui date picker working with angular2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35089638/how-to-get-jquery-ui-date-picker-working-with-angular2)

Comment: possible dupicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/35089638/5043867 you can edit your question instead of posting new one !

Comment: Yeh but know one has been helpful there

Comment: You should follow up and clarify if the answers have helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following.

```
import {Component, OnInit, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
   selector:'calendar',
   template:'<h3>calendar</h3><div id="calendar"></div>'
})
export class jQCalendar implements OnInit{

  constructor(){}
  ngOnInit(){
    var calendar =  (<HTMLSelectElement>document.getElementById('calendar'));
    $(calendar).datepicker();
  }

}
```

Here is a plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/92E0Er6kUxIS4E8hRgwI?p=preview

Comment: it would be better if you provide working plnkr or fiddle link !

Comment: Calendar at PrimeNG is based on jQuery UI datepicker, code is open source. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar