# How to assign selected date Value in Selected angular 2 ngModel?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I have three date fields in my form. I'm using jquery datepicker for that fields.
I have a code for adding the changed date in `ngModel` attribute. but that is for one field only.

For Example This is my Component Code

```js
$(".date").datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  yearRange: "1:100",
  format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
  changeYear: true
}).on('change', e => this.SelectedData.Misc1 = e.target.value);
```

This is my html code

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control date" id="Dat_Misc1" name="Misc1" [(ngModel)]="SelectedData.Misc1">
<input type="text" class="form-control date" id="Dat_Misc2" name="Misc2" [(ngModel)]="SelectedData.Misc2">
<input type="text" class="form-control date" id="Dat_Misc3" name="Misc3" [(ngModel)]="SelectedData.Misc3">
```

Here the change function assigning the value in one property only. But I need that one as dynamic. Whatever Date Field I select that should fetch the date value on that `ngModel`.

Please help me. Thanks in Advance..!

Comment: Check the value 'this.SelectedData' you will get the three model values

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35089638/863110) could help

Comment: While binding I'm getting the values @Vignesh.. But If I Change the date via datepicker the values not changing in ng-reflect-model.. !!

Comment: Try this$(".date").datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  yearRange: "1:100",
  format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
  changeYear: true
}).on('input change', e => this.SelectedData.Misc1 = e.target.value);

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery on input alongside with the on change event

```
$(".date").datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  yearRange: "1:100",
  format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
  changeYear: true
}).on('input change', e => this.SelectedData.Misc1 = e.target.value);
```

Comment: Problem is this part Vignesh..

e => this.SelectedData.Misc1 = e.target.value;

I don't want this.selectedData.Misc1.. Instead of that I need dynamic ngModel. Now this is assigning the value in only that misc1 ngModel.