# How to import jquery and mCustomScrollbar plugin into Angular2 component

Tags: jquery, angular, mcustomscrollbar

I have a problem with import these modules to my angular2 component. I using angular2-webpack-starter from AngularClass.

I install dependecies with npm:

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin --save
```

and install typings:

```
typings install jquery --save --ambient
typings install mcustomscrollbar --save --ambient
```

And i want to use it in component like this:

```
jQuery('.selector').mCustomScrollbar();
```

What is the best solution to do that?

I tried to use this solution: [Whats the best way to use jquery widgets inside angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600151/whats-the-best-way-to-use-jquery-widgets-inside-angular-2)

But it's not work, i got error "jQuery is not defined".

Answer (score 10):

**USING**
Angular: 2.0.0
Typescript: 2.0.2
Angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.16
webpack: 2.1.0-beta.22
node: 4.6
npm: 2.15.9

**ANSWER**
Add types to src/tsconfig.json

**SOLUTION**

1. Get Required packages
   `npm install jquery malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin --save`
   `npm install @types/jquery @types/jquery-mousewheel @types/mcustomscrollbar --save-dev`
2. Add plugin css and scripts to angular-cli.json in your root folder

   ```
   //angular-cli.json
   "apps": [
       {
           ...,
           "styles": [
               ...,
               "../node_modules/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css"
           ],
           "scripts": [
               "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
               "../node_modules/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/node_modules/jquery-mousewheel/jquery.mousewheel.js",
               "../node_modules/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"
           ],
           ...
       }
   ]
   ```
3. Add types to src/tsconfig.json

   ```
   //tsconfig.json
   {
       "compilerOptions": {
           ...,
           "typeRoots": [
               "../node_modules/@types/"
           ],
           "types": [
               "jquery","jquery-mousewheel","mCustomScrollbar"
           ],
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
4. Make Directive

   ```
   //scrollbar.directive.ts
   import {Directive, ElementRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
   declare var $:any;  //<-- let typescript compiler know your referencing a var that was already declared

   @Directive({
       selector: 'scrollbar',
       host: {'class':'mCustomScrollbar'},  //<-- Make sure you add the class
   })
   export class ScrollbarDirective implements OnInit {
       el: ElementRef;
       constructor(el:ElementRef) {
           this.el = el;
       }
       ngOnInit() {
           //$(function(){ console.log('Hello'); }); <--TEST JQUERY
           //check if your plugins are loading
           //$().mousewheel) ? console.log('mousewheel loaded') : console.log('mousewheel not loaded');
           //$().mCustomScrollbar) ? console.log('mCustomScrollbar loaded') : console.log('mCustomScrollbar not loaded');

           $(this.el.nativeElement).mCustomScrollbar({
               autoHideScrollbar: false,
               theme: "light",
               advanced: {
                   updateOnContentResize: true
               }
       });
   ```
5. Include directive in ngModule and apply in your component's template

   ```
   //app.module.ts
   import {ScrollbarDirective} from "./shared/UI/scrollbar.directive";
   import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";

   @NgModule({
   ...
       declarations: [
           AppComponent,
           ...,
           ScrollbarDirective
       ],
   ...
   })
   export class AppModule{}
   ```

   ---

   ```
   //app.component.ts
   @Component({
       selector: 'dashboard',
       templateUrl: `
           <scrollbar>
               <div *ngFor="let thing of things">thing</div><br/>
           </scrollbar>
       `
   })
   ```

Comment: Hey Thanks, for such a well constructed answer.  I have learned a lot form this!

Comment: Thanks for your great answer my friend!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to include JQuery and plugin somewhere in your page:

Answer (score 0):

You have to include jquery/plugin via script tag in your index.html page.

Assuming you are using TypeScript you can refer to jquery from the component like this:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';

declare var jQuery:any;
@Component({
    selector: 'jquery-integration',
    templateUrl: './components/jquery-integration/jquery-integration.html'
})
export class JqueryIntegration implements OnInit {
    elementRef: ElementRef;
    constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
        this.elementRef = elementRef;
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).mCustomScrollbar();
    }
}
```

More info here: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/using-jquery-with-angular-2.0