# using jQuery globally within Angular 2 application

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, npm

I'm trying to figure out how to use jQuery globally within my angular 2 app, the only reasonable source I found so far is this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30662773/911930) However I can't seem to get it working. Is there a way to achieve this with `npm` package management instead of tsd (this command is not working for me, I assumed it is coming from typescript, but seems like not).

After this, I think I need to reference jQuery within my app.ts file? (main file used by bootstrap.ts to boot the application)

Here is my project structure

```
app
  components
    app.ts
  services
  typings
  bootstrap.ts
index.html
```

and few code examples I believe need to be used for jQuery implementation

**app.ts**

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/app.html'
})

export class App { }
```

**bootstrap.ts**

```
import {App}              from './components/app';

bootstrap(App);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the jquery typings using:

```
npm install @types/jquery
```

Include the `jQuery.js` file in your `index.html`

And.. that's it I guess :)

Good luck

Comment: And I assume I need to include desired version of jQuery in html right?

Comment: Yes, indeed. A reference in typescript tells the compiler that you take care of adding the required javascript

Comment: fyi, tsd is the typescript definition manager. You can install this by running `npm -g install tsd`. After that you can install definition files like jQuery by running `tsd install jquery` :). This way you do not have to download them manually

Comment: @PierreDuc Now on `angular 2` how is the `typings` used as we don't use typings anymore, and we use `npm` to get the dependencies.

Comment: @PaladiN You can install them using this: `npm install @types/jquery`. Together with including the jquery.js in your index.html