# JQueryUI Sortable not working when using custom component with Angular2

Tags: jquery-ui, angular, jquery-ui-sortable

My aim is to be able to allow users to sort a list of commands. I am developing my application using Angular2/Typescript.

So I looked around for angular2 based libraries that may provide sortable functionality similar to JQueryUI Sortable, But couldn't find much.

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35054004/how-to-use-jquery-with-javascript-in-angular-2) SO post, which demonstrated how to integrate JQuery with angular2. Using the plunk provided in one of the solutions for this post, I could develop a sortable behavior with angular2. See this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/IvYyBKFxzSnEbCRaUeRL?p=preview). This is working as expected.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [SMSortable],
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>This is a list that can be sorted </p>
      <div sm-sortable>
        <p>Item 1</p>
        <p>Item 2</p>
        <p>Item 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}
```

The idea was to define a directive which would apply the sortable behavior to the native element using JQueryUI sortable() API. And then use the directive in the component's template.

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[sm-sortable]"
})
export class SMSortable{

    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        jQuery(el.nativeElement).sortable( {
              start: function(event, ui) {
                  console.log("Old position: " + ui.item.index());
              },
              stop: function(event, ui) {
                  console.log("New position: " + ui.item.index());
              }
        });
    }
}
```

This works well when the component's template has all native elements. But if my template has custom angular2 components, this stops working.

See this [not-working plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/tqddjpLzVdrA4GvjhUw4).

```
@Component ({
  selector: 'sm-cmd',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class SMCommand {

}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [SMSortable, SMCommand],
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>This is a list that can be sorted </p>
      <div sm-sortable>
        <sm-cmd><p>Item 1</p></sm-cmd>
        <sm-cmd><p>Item 2</p></sm-cmd>
        <sm-cmd><p>Item 3</p></sm-cmd>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class App {

}
```

In this case I am able to drag the item, but not able to drop it. The moved item reverts back to its original location. I added console.log to see the item index at start and stop event during sort. The value remains same.

I am not able to debug further on this. Could somebody provide some input on this?

Comment: Post non-working plunkr.

Comment: not-working plunker actually is working - wrong link?

Comment: Yes non working is working in fact.

Comment: Strange, its not working when I run this plunk. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/tqddjpLzVdrA4GvjhUw4?p=preview

Comment: Which browser? I am with chrome 49.

Comment: I see it now. It dragging works, but when dropped, it returns to its old position.

Comment: I just tried in firefox, it works there. Not sure why this is not working in chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is actually very simple: since you are using custom element `sm-cmd` browser doesn't know what rendering-model to use (block or inline). By default it applies inline one, which results into a collision in terms of element dimensions, because you have block-level `p` inside inline `sm-cmd`. So the browser doesn't calculate block dimensions properly.

So the solution is this simple CSS rule:

```
sm-cmd {display: block;}
```

Also make sure you initialize jQuery plugin in ngAfterViewInit hook:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[sm-sortable]"
})
export class SMSortable{

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      jQuery(this.el.nativeElement).sortable( {
            start: function(event, ui) {
                console.log("Old position: " + ui.item.index());
            },
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                console.log("New position: " + ui.item.index());
            }
      });
  }
}
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/QEd9wozXSZlqT07qr51h?p=preview