# Angular 2 DatePicker with month and year only

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am currently using https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker as the date picker for my Angular 2 application. I want a date picker which shows only month and year for angular 2. Does any one know how to do it. I tried Jquery for angular 2 but was unsuccessful.

Comment: If you are having a problem using jquery with angular 2(which is highly discouraged) then refer to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35055539/4593335).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

month-picker

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Month} from './month';

@Component({
    selector: 'month-picker',

    template: `
    <div>

    <div class="col-xs-2">      
    <select class="form-control"  required>
            <option  *ngFor="let p of months"  [selected]="mm === p.val ">{{p.name}}</option>    
    </select>
    </div>

    </div>`
})

export class MonthPicker implements OnInit {

private mm : string ;
months = [
        { val: '01'  name: 'Jan' },
        { val: '02'  name: 'Feb' },
        { val: '03'  name: 'Mar' },
        { val: '04'  name: 'Apr' },
        { val: '05'  name: 'May' },
        { val: '06'  name: 'Jun' },
        { val: '07'  name: 'Jul' },
        { val: '08'  name: 'Aug' },
        { val: '09'  name: 'Sep' },
        { val: '10'  name: 'Oct' },
        { val: '11'  name: 'Nov' },
        { val: '12'  name: 'Dec' }
    ];

    ngOnInit() {  this.getMonth(); 

    }  

    getMonth(){
    var today = new Date();
    this.mm = today.getMonth()+1;     
    if(this.mm<10) {
    this.mm='0'+this.mm        
        }
    }




}
```

month.ts

```
export class Month {  
    private val: string;
    private name: string;
}
```

YearPicker

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'year-picker',

    template: `
    <div>

    <div class="col-xs-2">      
    <select class="form-control"  required>
            <option  *ngFor="let y of years"  [selected]="yy === y ">{{y}}</option>    
    </select>
    </div>

    </div>`
})

export class YearPicker implements OnInit {


private years: number[] =[];
private yy : number;

    ngOnInit() { 
    this.getYear();

    }  

     getYear(){
        var today = new Date();
        this.yy = today.getFullYear();        
        for(var i = (this.yy-100); i <= this.yy; i++){
        this.years.push(i);}
    }


}
```

In my app component Html I use

```
<month-picker (change)="onMonthChange($event.target.value)"> </month-picker>
<year-picker (change)="onYearChange($event.target.value)"></year-picker>
```

Comment: months variable gives error

Comment: worked with ngModel in my case: <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
         <select class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="mm">
          <option  *ngFor="let p of months" [value]="p.val">{{p.name}}</option>    
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <select class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="yy">
            <option  *ngFor="let y of years"  [value]="y">{{y}}</option>    
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

Answer (score 1):

In your component.ts,

```
  months;
  years = [];

  getDates() {
    var date = new Date();
    var currentYear = date.getFullYear();

    //set values for year dropdown
    for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
      this.years.push(currentYear + i);
    }

    //set values for month dropdown
    this.months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
  }
```

In component.html,

```
  <select name="month" formControlName="monthName">
    <option *ngFor="let month of months" [ngValue]="month">
      {{month}}
    </option>
  </select>
  <select name="year" formControlName="year">
    <option *ngFor="let year of years" [ngValue]="year">
      {{year}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this https://musthaan.com/2017/08/28/month-picker-in-angular-2/

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener } from '@angular/core';<span                data-mce-type="bookmark"                id="mce_SELREST_start"              data-mce-style="overflow:hidden;line-height:0"              style="overflow:hidden;line-height:0"           ></span>

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-month-picker',
    templateUrl: 'monthPicker.html'
})
export class monthPickerDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    @Input() model: string|Date;
    @Input() config: ImonthPickerConfig;
    @Output() modelChange  = new EventEmitter();
    __monthPicker: monthPicker;
    constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
        this.__monthPicker = new monthPicker();
    }
    ngOnInit() {
    }
    ngOnChanges(changes:any) {
        if (this.model) {
            this.__monthPicker.setCurrentdate(new Date(this.model));
        }
    }

    onCalendarIconClick() {
        this.switchToMonthMode();
        this.__monthPicker.setCurrentdate(this.model ? new Date(this.model):new Date());
        this.__monthPicker.toggleState();
    }
    switchToYearMode() {
        this.__monthPicker.viewMode = 'y';
        this.__monthPicker.fillYearsInSelectionList();
    }
    switchToMonthMode() {
        this.__monthPicker.viewMode = 'm';
        this.__monthPicker.fillMonthsInSelectionList();
    }
    onselectionItemClick(item: IDatePickerSelectionItem) {
        if (item.type == 'y') {
            this.__monthPicker.displayYear = item.value;
            this.switchToMonthMode();
        } else if (item.type == 'm') {
            this.onSelectMonth(item);
        }
    }
    onSelectMonth(item: IDatePickerSelectionItem) {
        this.__monthPicker.displayMonth = item.text;
        this.__monthPicker.displayMonthIndex = item.value;

        this.__monthPicker.selectedMonth = item.text;
        this.__monthPicker.selectedMonthIndex = item.value;
        this.__monthPicker.selectedYear = this.__monthPicker.displayYear;

        this.model = (this.__monthPicker.selectedMonthIndex + 1) + "/01/" + this.__monthPicker.selectedYear;
        //this.model = new Date(this.__monthPicker.selectedYear, this.__monthPicker.selectedMonthIndex, 1);
        this.__monthPicker.state = "closed";
        this.modelChange.next(this.model);
    }

    onPrevYearSelection() {
        this.__monthPicker.displayYear--;
        if (this.__monthPicker.viewMode == 'y') { this.__monthPicker.fillYearsInSelectionList(); }
    }
    onNextYearSelection() {
        this.__monthPicker.displayYear++;
        if (this.__monthPicker.viewMode == 'y') { this.__monthPicker.fillYearsInSelectionList(); }
    }

    onCancel() {
        this.__monthPicker.state = "closed";
    }

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event', '$event.target'])
    public onClick(event: MouseEvent, targetElement: HTMLElement): void {
        if (!targetElement) {
            return;
        }

        const clickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
        if (!clickedInside) {
            this.__monthPicker.state = "closed";
        }
    }
}
export interface ImonthPickerConfig {
    readonly?: boolean;
    cssClass?: string;
    placeHolder?: string;
}
export interface IDatePickerSelectionItem {
    text: string;
    value: number;
    type: string;
}
class monthPicker {
    state: string;
    selectionItems: Array<IDatePickerSelectionItem>;
    selectedMonth: string;
    selectedMonthIndex: number;
    selectedYear: number;
    displayMonth: string;
    displayMonthIndex: number;
    displayYear: number;
    viewMode: string;
    private months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    constructor() {
        this.state = "closed";
        this.viewMode = 'm';
        this.fillMonthsInSelectionList();
        let currentDate = new Date();
        this.setCurrentdate(currentDate);
    }
    toggleState() {
        this.state = this.state == "closed" ? "open" : "closed";
    }

    fillMonthsInSelectionList() {
        this.selectionItems = [];
        this.months.forEach((v: string, i: number) => this.selectionItems.push({ text: v, value: i, type: 'm' }));
    }
    fillYearsInSelectionList() {
        this.selectionItems = [];
        for (let start = this.displayYear - 6; start <= this.displayYear + 5; start++) {
            this.selectionItems.push({ text: start.toString(), value: start, type: 'y' });
        }
    }
    setCurrentdate(currentDate: Date)
    {
        this.displayMonth = this.months[(currentDate.getMonth() - 1)];
        this.displayMonthIndex = currentDate.getMonth();
        this.displayYear = currentDate.getFullYear();

        this.selectedMonth = this.displayMonth;
        this.selectedMonthIndex = this.displayMonthIndex;
        this.selectedYear = this.displayYear;
    }
}
```

HTML Template

```
<div class="input-group fdms-mp-input">
    <input type="text" readonly value="{{model|date: 'MM/yyyy'}}" class="form-control" placeholder="{{config.placeHolder}}" />
    <span class="input-group-addon" (click)="onCalendarIconClick()"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
<div class="fdms-month-picker" *ngIf="__monthPicker.state=='open'">
<div class="col-md-12 d-title">{{__monthPicker.selectedMonth}}, {{__monthPicker.selectedYear}}</div>
<div class="col-md-12 d-nav">
<div class="col-md-3"><span (click)="onPrevYearSelection()"><</span></div>
<div class="col-md-6"><span (click)="switchToYearMode()">{{__monthPicker.displayYear}}</span></div>
<div class="col-md-3"><span (click)="onNextYearSelection()">></span></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 d-selection-wraper">
<div class="col-md-3 d-selection-item" *ngFor="let item of __monthPicker.selectionItems">
                <span (click)="onselectionItemClick(item)">{{item.text}}</span></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 d-actions">
            <span class="d-action d-action-cancel" (click)="onCancel()">Cancel</span></div>
</div>
</div>
```