# Correct way to use libraries like jquery/jqueryui inside angular 2 component

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I have researched this topic a bit and found out about typings for libraries that need to be used for typescript. What I struggled to find is examples of usage, lets say for jquery inside an angular 2 application.

here are some questions:

1) Where would one write his jQuery code, is it inside class or inside   constructor of that class?

2) Do we need to use document.ready at any point to wrap jQuery code? i.e. if we write code inside constructor is it run after this event?

few examples of usage, is one of these correct?

**example 1**

```
export class MyApp {
   constructor() {
      $('.mydiv').hide();
   }
}
```

**example 2**

```
export class MyApp {
   constructor() {
   }

   $('.mydiv').hide();
}
```

**example 3**

```
export class MyApp {
   constructor() {
   }

   $( document ).ready(function() {
     $('.mydiv').hide();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ideally you should wait till component content get initialized, in order to make the DOM available on which you wanted to apply `jQuery`. For that you need to use `AfterViewInit` which is one of [**hook of angular2 lifecycle**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html).

You need to implement `AfterViewInit` on a class and write add `ngAfterViewInit` method to get notify whenever component content gets ready.

```
import { AfterViewInit } from 'angular2/core';

export class MyApp implements AfterViewInit {
   constructor() {
   }

   ngAfterViewInit(){
       //here you will have code where component content is ready.
       $('.mydiv').hide();
   } 
}
```

Comment: referring your code i tried to add `materializecss <select>` as `$('select').material_select();` but it is showing error on `material_select()` that class doesn't exists. Can u tell me correct implementaton? [materialize](http://materializecss.com/forms.html)

Comment: @Dimple could you provide me a plunkr of the same?

Comment: See [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/q0WlWjOONTJk9e1tSsZL?p=preview). I have added select tag since it is not getting displayed

Comment: @Dimple You first need to make your jQuery working by adding `jQuery` typing, please refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular2) for the same

Comment: @Dimple look at browser in your plunkr, it clear says that. `$` is not defined..you could add question here to get other people to involve you to get helped out..

Comment: Check now.. It shows select tag but still shows error and in VS it shows error `Property material_select() does not exists on type 'ElementFinder'`

Comment: @Dimple [this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/q0WlWjOONTJk9e1tSsZL?p=preview) seems working on my end

Comment: Yes.. But this doesn't work for datepicker. Updated Plunker. And refer [materialize](http://materializecss.com/forms.html)

Comment: @Dimple do gather all information together & then add it as an question.. there is not meaning to have conversation in comments.. this will never gonna end then..

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to start by answering your second question. Yes, you should use `document.ready` because its intention is to wait until the DOM is loaded. If it's not loaded, your jQuery code won't work.

Now to answer your first question, once loaded, it shouldn't matter where you call jQuery.

See [this](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: I'd be very surprised if Angular starts creating components before the DOM is loaded.  So, I doubt we need to use `document.ready` (but I haven't researched it, so I can't state that as a fact.)

Comment: Agreed, by using Angular it's likely the DOM is already loaded and you shouldn't need to specify `document.ready`. It should work, but would be redundant since it's already loaded.