# How to get source code of html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a link for an example of Edit source Code:

http://neokoenig.github.io/jQuery-gridmanager/demo/tinymce.html

the button which value is `</>`.

He get the code HTML even if he changes the content of the grid.

How to get the source code HTML using JavaScript or jQuery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the html method with jquery, i.e for get the whole page html like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log($("html").html());
})
```

Comment: this html() get code html after is genereted I need to get code html as I typed in my IDE

Comment: i'm trying to understand what you want to do. but i can't lol... please tell us what you want to do

Comment: I'm working with angular2 and there is some input wich I add in html code like this <input [name] type="text" /> and when I get my code using method html() I dont get [name] as I typed in my IDE(intellij)

Comment: but do you see the input rendered in the document??? if yes use 'html();' into a document ready function

Comment: can you give an example for using html() into a document ready function

Comment: I get code html bu with the same problem the pronlem I think becomes from angular2 Apps

Comment: but do you see the input in the browser??? use the inspect element options in the browser and tell me what is inside... look at this question may be could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35072199/correct-way-to-use-libraries-like-jquery-jqueryui-inside-angular-2-component

Comment: I see it in inspect element it gives me the same result as html(); method
for example  [dropzones]="zone1" becomes ng-reflect-dropzones="zone1"

Answer (score 2):

Using JavaScript

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

[More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

or

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

[More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to do exactly but if you want to get raw source code from jQuery you can use the following:

```
var html = $('element').html();
```

And with pure javascript from an id

```
var html = document.getElementById('id').innerHTML;
```

or from classname

```
var html = document.getElementsByClassName('class').innerHTML;
```

And to get the content of your example (which is an editor called tinymce) you can use the command `tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();` or `tinyMCE.get('myTextarea').getContent()`

---

EDIT:
If you want to listen for changes with jQuery and display to html dynamically you'd want to do something like this:

```
$('yourTextArea').keyup(function() {
    var html = $(this).val();
    $('yourElementToDisplayTheHTML').html(html);
});
```

Comment: this html() get code html after is genereted 
I need to get code html as I typed in my IDE

Comment: Do you mean like an event listener while typing that displays your html instantly? Are you using tinymce or just an textarea/input?

Comment: yess some things like that when I add some code dynamically in my page html I want it be dsplayed (I'm not using tinymce)

Answer (score 0):

I've built a simple API, just use this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Parking-Master/viewsource@latest/vs.js"></script>
```

In your JavaScript:

```
getSource('https://example.com/');
```

Answer (score -2):

in http response header, you can find "content-type" header. that header indicates how contents of page should be rendered. so, if you want to render page as plain text("source code", as you mentioned), just change that header like this -> "content-type : text/plain; charset=UTF-8"

if you can use ajax in jquery or javascript

use like this

```
$("button").click(function(){
$.ajax({url: "page_you_want.html", success: function(result){
    alert(result);
}});
```

});

Comment: This has nothing to do with requests and therefore no headers. OP need to get raw html contents from his editor.