# How to use code to open a modal in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

Usually we use `data-target="#myModal"` in the `<button>` to open a modal. Right now I need use codes to control when to open the modal.

If I use `[hidden]` or `*ngIf` to show it, I need remove `class="modal fade"`, otherwise, the modal will never show. Like this:

```
<div [hidden]="hideModal" id="myModal">
```

However, in this case, after removing `class="modal fade"`, the modal won't fade in and has no shade in the background. And what's worse, it will show at the screen bottom instead of screen center.

Is there a way to keep `class="modal fade"` and use code to open it?

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why to  use `[hidden]`  in the modal ?

Comment: @PardeepJain As I said, [hidden] and class="modal fade" together the modal will never show even [hidden]="false". If u want to use [hidden], u need remove class="modal fade"

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This is one way I found. You can add a hidden button:

```
<button id="openModalButton" [hidden]="true" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

Then use the code to "click" the button to open the modal:

```
document.getElementById("openModalButton").click();
```

This way can keep the bootstrap style of the modal and the fade in animation.

Comment: This does not work at compile time and not with typescript. Its sort of hackish

Comment: The link `http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/modals` results in a 404 today...

Comment: @gogognome thanks, I just removed that link, because nowadays there are many packages available if the person choose to use a package.

Comment: Thank you alot. Coolest solution. I don't use 3rd party bootstrap in angular. I just copy links from official site. I don't like too much of code jungle and i open popup only after data is loaded from backend.This is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 34):

Include jQuery as usual inside script tags in index.html.

After all the imports but before declaring @Component, add:

```
declare var $: any;
```

Now you are free to use jQuery anywhere in your Angular 2 TypeScript code:

```
$("#myModal").modal('show');
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38246116/2473022

Comment: I do it this way. Bootstrap 3 depends somewhat on jquery.

Comment: The best answer without installing a third party package. jQuery should be installed when using Bootstrap, so might as well use it in the controller and this way is also in the Bootstrap docs. Thanks

Comment: Don't forget link or install bootstrap.js

Comment: jQuery shouldn't be used wtih Angular 2+

Answer (score 13):

Easy way to achieve this in **angular 2 or 4**  *(Assuming that you are using **bootstrap 4**)*

> Component.html

```html
<button type="button" (click)="openModel()">Open Modal</button>

<div #myModel class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title ">Title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" (click)="closeModel()">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('myModal') myModal;

openModel() {
  this.myModal.nativeElement.className = 'modal fade show';
}
closeModel() {
   this.myModal.nativeElement.className = 'modal hide';
}
```

Comment: Could you please specify where in your solution you assumed usage of Bootstrap 4 instead of 3? I am using version 3 and this worked for me anyway, so I think I missed some detail and would like to learn more :)

Comment: @MaxAxeHax I use word "Assuming using bootstarp 4", Just in case previous or upcoming version of bootstrap class for hide and show is change then you just need to replace that class in openModel and closeModel function.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Neither the snippet nor code based on it.

Comment: Doesn't work. Neither the snippet nor code based on i

Answer (score 12):

The below answer is in reference to the latest [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples)

**Install**

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...

    NgbModule

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Component Controller**

```js
import { TemplateRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-app-registration',
  templateUrl: './app-registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-registration.component.css']
})

export class AppRegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('editModal') editModal : TemplateRef<any>; // Note: TemplateRef

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

  openModal(){
    this.modalService.open(this.editModal);
  }

}
```

**Component HTML**

```html
<ng-template #editModal let-modal>

<div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Edit Form</h4>
  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss()">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
  
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="dateOfBirth">Date of birth</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input id="dateOfBirth" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" ngbDatepicker #dp="ngbDatepicker">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="dp.toggle()" type="button"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close()">Save</button>
</div>

</ng-template>
```

Comment: Very nice! I didn't note `TemplateRef<any>; // Note: TemplateRef` but it was important. Thanks, Arjun

Answer (score 7):

Best way I have found. Put `#lgModal` or some other variable name in your modal.

**In your view:**

```
<div bsModal #lgModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" (click)="lgModal.hide()" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Large modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**In your component**

```
import {Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/common';
// todo: change to ng2-bootstrap
import {MODAL_DIRECTIVES, BS_VIEW_PROVIDERS} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import {ModalDirective} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';


@Component({
  selector: 'modal-demo',
  directives: [MODAL_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  viewProviders:[BS_VIEW_PROVIDERS],
  templateUrl: '/app/components/modals/modalDemo.component.html'
})
export class ModalDemoComponent implements AfterViewInit{

  @ViewChild('childModal') public childModal: ModalDirective;
  @ViewChild('lgModal') public lgModal: ModalDirective;

  public showChildModal():void {
    this.childModal.show();
  }

  public hideChildModal():void {
    this.childModal.hide();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.lgModal.show();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is my full implementation of modal bootstrap angular2 component:

I assume that in your main index.html file (with `<html>` and `<body>` tags) at the bottom of `<body>` tag you have:

```
  <script src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

modal.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, ElementRef, EventEmitter, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;// this is very importnant (to work this line: this.modalEl.modal('show')) - don't do this (becouse this owerride jQuery which was changed by bootstrap, included in main html-body template): let $ = require('../../../../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');

@Component({
  selector: 'modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.html',
})
export class Modal implements AfterViewInit {

    @Input() title:string;
    @Input() showClose:boolean = true;
    @Output() onClose: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    modalEl = null;
    id: string = uniqueId('modal_');

    constructor(private _rootNode: ElementRef) {}

    open() {
        this.modalEl.modal('show');
    }

    close() {
        this.modalEl.modal('hide');
    }

    closeInternal() { // close modal when click on times button in up-right corner
        this.onClose.next(null); // emit event
        this.close();
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.modalEl = $(this._rootNode.nativeElement).find('div.modal');
    }

    has(selector) {
        return $(this._rootNode.nativeElement).find(selector).length;
    }
}

let modal_id: number = 0;
export function uniqueId(prefix: string): string {
    return prefix + ++modal_id;
}
```

modal.html:

```
<div class="modal inmodal fade" id="{{modal_id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true" #thisModal>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" [ngClass]="{'hide': !(has('mhead') || title) }">
                <button *ngIf="showClose" type="button" class="close" (click)="closeInternal()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <ng-content select="mhead"></ng-content>
                <h4 *ngIf='title' class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <ng-content></ng-content>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer" [ngClass]="{'hide': !has('mfoot') }" >
                <ng-content select="mfoot"></ng-content>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And example of usage in client Editor component:
client-edit-component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ClientService } from './client.service';
import { Modal } from '../common';

@Component({
  selector: 'client-edit',
  directives: [ Modal ],
  templateUrl: './client-edit.html',
  providers: [ ClientService ]
})
export class ClientEdit {

    _modal = null;

    constructor(private _ClientService: ClientService) {}

    bindModal(modal) {this._modal=modal;}

    open(client) {
        this._modal.open();
        console.log({client});
    }

    close() {
        this._modal.close();
    }

}
```

client-edit.html:

```
<modal [title]='"Some standard title"' [showClose]='true' (onClose)="close()" #editModal>{{ bindModal(editModal) }}
    <mhead>Som non-standart title</mhead>
    Some contents
    <mfoot><button calss='btn' (click)="close()">Close</button></mfoot>
</modal>
```

Ofcourse title, showClose, mhead and mfoot ar optional parameters.

Comment: could you please take a look at this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xesgxe I want to show a modal when `input` is clicked. But the compiler can't find `this.el.modal` or `this.el.nativeElement.modal()`

Comment: got it working using `$().modal`. It is in one of the answers below

Comment: In method `ngAfterViewInit` and methods `open/close` I in fact use it. However in this answer goal was to provide working "modal" component (with example usage) - however it was 2 years ago so may be now it is outdated.

Comment: Yes, I see it now. I am concerned about mixing jquery and angular code but this one is the only one I could get working. If you happen to find a soln. which is more Angular, please do update. So would I.

Comment: Could you please help me understand why this line is important `declare var $: any;`. I expected that because I have already included `jquery` in my project, I should be able to use `$` anywhere. Also, your comment that `becouse this override jQuery which was changed by bootstrap`. Does Bootstrap's come with its own implementation of `JQuery`?

Comment: I suppose I found the answer. By doing `declare var $:any`, we declare a variable that exists somewhere in the JS - found it from some other question in SO

Comment: @ManuChadha I ask more general similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50516233/import-third-party-js-files-to-angular-typescript-project

Answer (score 5):

I do not feel there is anything wrong with using JQuery with angular and bootstrap, since it is included when adding bootstrap.

1. Add the $ right after the imports like this

```
import {.......

declare var $: any;

@component.....
```

2. modal should have an id like this

`<div id="errorModal" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" ..............`

3. then have a method like this

`showErrorModal() {
 $("#errorModal").modal('show');
 }`

4. call the method on a button click or anywhere you wish

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently using Bootstrap 4.3 in Angular 8 and want to open modal window programmatically (without actually clicking on some button as the official demo shows).

Following method works for me:
The general idea is to create a button associated to a modal window. 
First make sure after you click this button, it can open the modal.
Then give this button tag an id using hashtag, for example `#hiddenBtn`.
In component ts file, `import ViewChild from @angular/core` and write below code:

```
@ViewChild('hiddenBtn', {static: false}) myHiddenBtn;
```

After that, whenever you want to open this modal window in your component ts code, write following code to simulate click operation

```
this.myHiddenBtn.nativeElement.click();
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Nice solution! Even if not the Angular way :)

Answer (score 2):

Think I found the correct way to do it using **ngx-bootstrap**. First import following classes:

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService, ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';
```

Inside the class implementation of your component add a @ViewCild property, a function to open the modal and do not forget to setup modalService as a private property inside the components class constructor:

```
@ViewChild('editSomething') editSomethingModal : TemplateRef<any>;
...

modalRef: BsModalRef;
openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
  this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
}
...
constructor(
private modalService: BsModalService) { }
```

The 'editSomething' part of the @ViewChild declaration refers to the component template file and its modal template implementation (**#editSomething**):

```
...
<ng-template #editSomething>
  <div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Edit ...</h4>
  <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" 
   (click)="modalRef.hide()">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>


  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
        (click)="modalRef.hide()"
        >Close</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

And finaly call the method to open the modal wherever you want like so:

```
console.log(this.editSomethingModal);
this.openModal( this.editSomethingModal );
```

> this.editSomethingModal
>   is a **TemplateRef** that could be shown by the ModalService.

Et voila! The modal defined in your component template file is shown by a call from inside your component class implementation. In my case I used this to show a modal from inside an event handler.

Answer (score 0):

The Way i used to do it without lots of coding is..
I have the hidden button with the `id="employeeRegistered"`

On my `.ts` file I `import ElementRef from '@angular/core'`

Then after I process everything on my `(click)` method do as follow:

`this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#employeeRegistered').click();`

then the modal displays as expected..

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to settimeout in addition to @arjun-sk solution's ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400811/how-to-use-code-to-open-a-modal-in-angular-2/53801570#53801570)), as I was getting the [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292932/expression-has-changed-error-on-opening-a-modal-popup-inside-a-component)

```
setTimeout(() => {
      this.modalService.open(this.loginModal, { centered: true })
    }, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using a variable to control show and hide and rely on the button the open the modal

ts code:

```
showModel(){
  this.showModal = true;
}
```

html:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" (click)="showModel()>Open Modal</button>

<div *ngIf="showModal" >
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use jquery to open bootstrap modal.

```
ngAfterViewInit() { 
      $('#scanModal').modal('show'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap npm I m using for this as in the project bootstrap is used, for material, we used dialog

HTML Code

```
  <span (click)="openModal(modalRef)" class="form-control input-underline pl-3 ">Open Abc Modal
 </span>
```

Modal template

```
<ng-template class="custom-modal"  #modalRef let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
   <div class="modal-header custom-modal-head"><h4 class="modal-title">List of Countries</h4>
     <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
         <img src="assets/actor/images/close.png" alt="">
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body country-select">
       <div class="serch-field">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                 <input type="text"  class="form-control input-underline pl-3" placeholder="Search Country"
                    [(ngModel)]="countryWorkQuery" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                 <ul *ngIf="countries" class="ng-star-inserted">
                   <li (click)="setSelectedCountry(cntry, 'work');d('Cross click');" class="cursor-pointer"
                   *ngFor="let cntry of countries | filterNames:countryWorkQuery ">{{cntry.name}}</li>
                 </ul>
                 <span *ngIf="!modalSpinner && (!countries || countries.length<=0)">No country found</span>
                 <span *ngIf="modalSpinner" class="loader">
                     <img src="assets/images/loader.gif" alt="loader">
                 </span>
               </div>
             </div>
       </div>
 </div>
</ng-template>
```

Ts File

```
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

constructor(
    private modalService: NgbModal
  ) { }

  openModal(modalContent){
     this.modalService.open(modalContent, { centered: true});
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, `npm install --save @types/bootstrap` try to match typing version with your bootstrap version. E.g. you have Bootstrap 4.3.1 then `npm install --save @types/bootstrap@4.3.1`

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain the solution.
Bit tricky
.......
Parent HTML File
........

```
<!-- parent component html -->
your code....
<div class="d-flex align-items-center flex-nowrap justify-content-end">
    <button (click)="openCancelStandingOrder(line)" class="btn btn-primary mx-1" type="button">Delete</button>
</div>
<div *ngIf="isCancelStandingOrderOpen">
    <child-component [data]="data" (onCloseModel)="onCloseModal($event)"></child-component>
</div>
```

Parent TS File

```
export class ParentComponent {
isCancelStandingOrderOpen: boolean = false;
data: any;
// ....
fetchData() {
// API Call
}

openCancelStandingOrder(line) {
this.isCancelStandingOrderOpen = true;
this.data = line;
}

onCloseModal(reload) {
// prevent unnessecery api calls
if (reload) {

// fetch list data again
this.fetchData();
}

// Do needful

}
}
```

Child HTML File

```
<ng-template #cancelStandingOrderModal let-modal>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Title</h4>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close" (click)="onDismiss(modal)"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <!--  your content here -->
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" (click)="onSubmit(modal)">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="onExit(modal)">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Child TS File

```
export class ChildComponent {
// ...
@Input() data: any; // Get data from parent
@Output() public onCloseModal: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
    @ViewChild('cancelStandingOrderModal', { static: false }) public formModal: TemplateRef<any>; // Note: Target html
        instance

        // Using bootstrap modals: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples
        constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

        ngOnInit() {
        // Any data manipulation
        }

        ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.openModal();
        }

        openModal() {
        this.modalService.open(this.formModal, {
        backdrop: false,
        centered: true,
        size: 'lg',
        keyboard: false, // disable ESC key to close
        });
        }

        onSubmit(modal) {
        // Do needful.. api calls etc....
        // ...
        this.closeModel(modal, true)
        }

        onExit(modal) {
        // Execute any mathod befor closing modal
        // like unsaved data alert etc.
        this.closeModel(modal, false)
        }


        onDismiss(modal) {
        this.closeModel(modal, false)
        }

        closeModel(modal: any, reload: boolean = false) {
        this.onCloseModal.emit(reload)
        modal.close('close');
        }
        }
```