# How to create a modal popup that is compatible with Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, popup, modal-dialog

I want to be able to create a popup window which will load a certain Angular 4 component of mine when a radio button is selected.

It seems that the methods listed in the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400811/how-to-use-codes-to-open-a-modal-in-angular-2) are only compatible with Angular 2.

I am not sure where to begin and would appreciate any help!

Comment: Check [Angular Material Dialogue](https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog), here is the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/KAGWxrHsub9wezcFaBZz?p=preview)

Comment: Awesome this seems to be exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Glad it helped, you may accept answer, Cheers!!

Comment: Also note that if a solution works with angular v2, it will almost certainly work with angular v4

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The accepted answer adds a large dependency to swat a fly.  Modal (and modeless) dialogs are largely the result of a CSS class or two. Try this "rename..." example:

1) Write the parent and child-modal as if the child wasn't modal at all, but just an inline form with *ngIf attached.

Parent HTML that uses `<my-modal>` child:

```
<div>
    A div for {{name}}.
    <button type="button" (click)="showModal()">Rename</button>
    <my-modal *ngIf="showIt" [oldname]="name" (close)="closeModal($event)"></my-modal>
</div>
```

Parent class. The `@Component` decorator omitted for brevity. (The `name` property belongs to the parent class and would exist even if we didn't have a form to alter it.)

```
export class AppComponent {
    name = "old name";

    showIt = false;
    showModal() {
        this.showIt = true;
    }
    closeModal(newName: string) {
        this.showIt = false;
        if (newName) this.name = newName;
    }

}
```

Child to-be-modal component. `@Component` decorator and imports again omitted.

```
export class MyModalComponent {
    @Input() oldname = "";
    @Output() close = new EventEmitter<string>();
    newname = "";

    ngOnInit() {
        // copy all inputs to avoid polluting them
        this.newname = this.oldname; 
    }

    ok() {
        this.close.emit(this.newname);
    }

    cancel() {
        this.close.emit(null);
    }
}
```

Child HTML before modal-izing it.

```
<div>
    Rename {{oldname}}
    <input type="text" (change)="newname = $event.target.value;" />
    <button type="button" (click)="ok()">OK</button>
    <button type="button" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

2) Here's the CSS for child, but it can be placed in a global stylesheet for re-use throughout your app. It's a single class called `modal` and is intended for a `<div>` element.

```
.modal {
    /* detach from rest of the document */
    position: fixed;

    /* center */
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    /* ensure in front of rest of page -- increase as needed */
    z-index: 1001;

    /* visual illusion of being in front -- alter to taste */
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 10px 10px 4px;

    /* visual illusion of being a solid object -- alter to taste */
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: 5px solid darkblue;

    /* visual preference of don't crowd the contents -- alter to taste */
    padding: 10px;
}
```

But the `modal` CSS class won't prevent interacting with the page underneath it. (So it technically creates a modeless dialog.) So we place an `overlay` underneath the modal to absorb and ignore mouse activity. `overlay` is also intended for a `<div>` element.

```
.overlay {
    /* detach from document */
    position: fixed;

    /* ensure in front of rest of page except modal */
    z-index: 1000;

    /* fill screen to catch mice */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 9999px;
    height: 9999px;

    /* dim screen 20% -- alter to taste */
    opacity: 0.2;
    background-color: black;
}
```

3) Use the `modal` and `overlay` in the child HTML.

```
<div class="modal">
    Rename {{oldname}}
    <input type="text" (change)="newname = $event.target.value;" />
    <button type="button" (click)="ok()">OK</button>
    <button type="button" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

And that's it.  Basically 2 CSS classes and you can make any component a modal.  In fact you can show a component in-line or as a modal at run-time just by altering the existance of the CSS class with `ngClass` or `[class.modal]="showAsModalBoolean"`.

You can alter this so the child controls the show/hide logic. Move the *ngIf, showIt, and show() function into the child.  In the parent add `@ViewChild(MyModalComponent) renameModal: MyModalComponent;` and then the parent can imperatively call `this.renameModal.show(this.name);` and re-wire initialization and containing divs as needed.

The child-modal can return info to a parent's function as shown above, or the child's `show()` method could instead accept a callback or return a Promise, as per taste.

Two things to know:

`this.renameModal.show(..);` won't work if there's an *ngIf on `<my-modal>` because it won't exist to expose the function to begin with. *ngIf removes the whole component, show() function and all, so use `[hidden]` instead if you need this for some reason.

Modals-on-modals will have z-index issues since they all share the same z-index. This can be solved with `[style.z-index]="calculatedValue"` or similar.

Comment: I really like this answer because it is lightweight and flexible, and it's written to teach you something instead of using a huge framework to accomplish a tiny task.

Comment: I'm trying to follow this code as well, but don't understand who should catch the emitted event? Does some part of the parent HTML handle this?

Comment: parent's HTML has `<my-modal (close)="closeModal($event)">` which is where the child's emitted `close` event is caught and routed to the parent controller's closeModal function.

Comment: To be honest, knowing we can use angular material to achieve this task is almost useless, if not harmful, to me. However what this answer lacks is that normally people won't use modal as a embedded component, instead they are always used as a service, ex. `modalObject.popup()` where this `modalObject` can be initialized on the fly. Therefore it should have no trace of this component in the aplication template.

Comment: love this answer. Simple, customizable and not dependant on other libraries.. Thanks..

Comment: @windmaomao I was surprised to learn a lot of React devs prefer the above inline approach. I wrote about when to prefer one over the other https://dev.to/ronnewcomb/modal-dialogs-as-a-promise-versus-inline-1d4l

Answer (score 13):

Check [Angular Material Dialogue](https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog), here is the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Dh9INs7QZPatSyhHywJc?p=preview)

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef} from '@angular/material';


@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-result-example',
  templateUrl: './dialog-result-example.html',
})
export class DialogResultExample {
  selectedOption: string;

  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog) {}

  openDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogResultExampleDialog);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.selectedOption = result;
    });
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-result-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog-result-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogResultExampleDialog {
  constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogResultExampleDialog>) {}
}
```

Comment: I am calling the openDialog() function in a sub-component rather than directly in the root so I do not want to bootstrap the dialog component in the main.ts (as this gives me a plethora of errors saying that this component did not match any elements). Would I need to give the sub-component something like its own module.ts? How do I resolve this?

Comment: MdDialog is part of Angular Material component suite, read [getting started guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) to set that up, it is as simple as installi material npm lib and including in your main module, Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you. With a bit of searching around, I was able to find the solution. I had to add 

"entryComponents: [DialogResultExampleDialog]"

Instead of bootstrapping it

Comment: this doesnt work.Cannot find module '@angular/material'.

Comment: @ritesh, did you npm install angular material? check this [getting started guide with Angular material](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)

Comment: The plunker fails to load for me.

Comment: @pauloya, thnks for letting me know, updated the URL, Cheers!!

Comment: I am getting this error in browser (compile is OK) using your solution: Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MdDialogRef: (?, ?)

Comment: I'm using @angular/core (and all other @angular packages in version 4.2.5).  So I tried ```npm install @angular/material@4.2.5```; it does not exists. With ```npm view @angular/material versions --json``` you can see that it jumps from version 2.x to 5.x. It does not exists in version 4 at all. Which one it is suppoesed to use for Angular4 ?