# Expression has changed error on Opening a Modal Popup inside a component

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, viewchild

I have a parent component and i am passing some HTML from it to a child common component using @ViewChild().

When Child component loads up a popup. Console throws below error.

**"ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: undefined'. Current value: 'ngIf: this is description'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook ?"**

**I am using { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';**

This is the code.

**Update - 
This parent component is called as app-parent-component in another parent html file.**

**Parent Component**

```
@ViewChild('templateToLoad') templateToLoad;


constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private ChangeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.openPopup();
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.ChangeDetector.detectChanges();
}

private openPopup() {
    const modalPrompt = this.modalService.open(CommonChildModalComponent, {windowClass: 'modal-prompt fade-in-down'});
    modalPrompt.componentInstance.title = 'Title';
    modalPrompt.componentInstance.contentTemplate = this.templateToLoad;
    modalPrompt.componentInstance.originContext = this;
    modalPrompt.componentInstance.description = 'ABC';
```

**Parent HTML**

```
<ng-template #templateToLoad>
  <div class="someClass">This data will be shown on Popup without any error.
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

**CommonChildPopup Component**

```
@Input() title?: string;
@Input() description?: string;
@Input() originContext: any;
@Input() contentTemplate?: any;

constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    console.log('I am here in CommonModalComponent ngOnInit');
}
```

CommonChildPopup HTML

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body pb-3" [class.dimmer]="simulateLoading">
  <p *ngIf="description">{{description}}</p>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="contentTemplate"></ng-container>
```

The above console error is for this line ngIf="description". If i remove this line, same error will come for next line. Please help.

Comment: the error is due to value of the variable being changed after the angular has checked the content. So whatever logic you are implementing to change the values , do it inside ``ngAfterContentChecked()``

Comment: I am not changing any values or any logic here.. whatever values I am setting in parent component, those should be loaded but somehow it is calling chid component and seeing undefined and second time it finds correct values.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're trying to update the property values in a lifecycle hook after they have been previously checked in the parent component.

The recommended solution is to open the modal on a button click / another user triggered event, or if you need to open it after the view is initialized you can use the setTimeout() that will skip a tick

`ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => this.openPopup());
  }`

**Working plunker** : https://plnkr.co/edit/FVV7QVp620lIGJwEhN6V?p=preview

A very nice and detailed explanation about this error : https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

Comment: I tried it but still same error. I added that line to fix the error but still nothing. :(

Comment: i AM new to this. I don't know how to make working app with this code on plunker. :(

Comment: thanx a lot.. it did really helped me .

Answer (score 12):

`ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: `'ng-untouched: true'`. Current value: `'ng-untouched: false'`.

`setTimeout` trick doesn't work for subscribing for reactive form either. The following workaround should work for me

html

```
<select [ngModel]="countryId"  #ngModelDir="ngModel"
      (ngModelChange)="fileChangeEvent($event, ngModelDir)">
```

ts

```
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
...
fileChangeEvent(event: any, ngModelDir: NgModel) {
  ngModelDir.control.markAsTouched();
  const modalRef = this.modalService.open(MymodalComponent, {
    keyboard: false,
    backdrop: 'static'
  });
}
```

Comment: This works! But I want to know why? and whats the reason because the control is not touched....

Comment: @Ismaestro When we open a modal window, the form element loses the focus. So need to mark the control in a form group as touched explicitly.

Comment: Still ! This code doesn't work in case of ng-select library for edit flow when you have multiple selected values coming in edit flow.

Answer (score 8):

In my case the error was happening in an Angular 4 application. The application needed to open an ng-bootrap modal when the user selected a value from a dropdown in a reactive form. Using the `setTimeout` workaround did not work. However, the solution described in the below link - i.e. setting the control to touched (by calling `markAsTouched()` on the control) resolved the error.

This issue is in Angular as described [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15634).

Comment: I've solved a very similar problem using this workaround in Angular 8.2.4. Thank you for saving my night.