# Show modal window after Http.get()

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm calling a function to get a response from Http.get() request.

My data retrieve function is this one:

```
getCharacterDetail(characterId: number) {
    return this.http.get(this.characterDetailApiUrl + characterId)
        .subscribe(res =>
            console.log(res.json())
        );
}
```

Now I have to show this data into a modal window. No idea of what to do.

Comment: how does your dom look like? material dialog? bootstrap modal?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using bootstrap 3 so, yes, gonna use bootstrap modal

Comment: I personally find this solution not so clean, so I switched to use angular material. But if you wanna use bootstrap modal with angular. Here is what you can do. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400811/how-to-use-code-to-open-a-modal-in-angular-2

Comment: Well, I can use Angular Material as well. There is no problem

Comment: Think about what you wanna do, then go for it. I'm not saying materia.angular.io is better. I just wanna try it out and learn it. It's pretty new, so they don't have many components like bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Using the code you've provided, here's a rough estimate of what you might be looking for.

```
app.controller('characterController', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.getCharacterDetail = function (number) {
     return $http.get(this.characterDetailApiUrl + characterId)
       .subscribe(res =>
           console.log(res.json())
       );
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

ng-bootrstrap would be a good option because modal component is available where you could pass the necessary data as an input to the component.

[example](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples)

Comment: Finnaly I'm gonna use ng-bootstrap but fon't know how to implement inside my app.component.ts. :( How to work with more than 1 component in Typescript and make a relation between them