# Import third party js files to angular typescript project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lib

During my experience in angular I was forced to use four different ways of include 3-rd party library [poliglot.js](https://github.com/airbnb/polyglot.js) (for multilang).

So to be able use `new Polyglot(...)` in my Lang class:

```
export class Lang
{
    ...
    constructor() {

        this.polyglot = new Polyglot({ locale: 'en' });
        ...        
    }
    ...
}
```

I use this four approach

**A.** In my quite old (2016) angular2 (based on framerwork [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter)) project (currently this solution doesn't work due to lack of `require` instruction in new angular projects):

```
var Polyglot = require('../../../node_modules/node-polyglot/build/polyglot.min.js');
```

**B.** In my next project angular4 (based on [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter)):

```
import Polyglot from '../../../node_modules/node-polyglot/build/polyglot.min.js';
```

**C.** In my recent angular5 project embeded in Laravel project (based on [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli))

```
import * as Polyglot from '../../../node_modules/node-polyglot/build/polyglot.min.js';
```

**D.** I also found 4-th solution which work on my some old angular project for jQuery (based on [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter)) (and people in internet mention this solution a lot)  but I write it down using Polyglot example:

```
import '../../../node_modules/node-polyglot/build/polyglot.min.js';
declare var Polyglot: any;

// declare var $:any   // this is for jquery (as example)
```

The questions are: **What is the difference between this four solutions and how they works? What cause that in some project one solution works but others does't work?**

Comment: It depends on how you set up your build.

Comment: @SLaks - can you give more details (and build setup examples)? Exactly what makes differences?

Comment: Do you use Webpack? Browserify? Something else?

Comment: @SLaks webpack (because angular-cli, angular-webpack-starter use it). I also wannt to **stressed** that polyglot.js library NOT changes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So lets break it down:

A: Would still work in any angular version you just have to declare require before using it.

```
declare const require: any;
const Polyglot = require('../../../node_modules/node-polyglot/build/polyglot.min.js');
```

B: Point A uses the CommonJS module system to load the dependency, the other points are using the ES6 dynamic import system (which can be used like the commonjs module system with [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/modules/) by default). You can import Polyglot directly if the library exposes the module e.g.

```
export class Polyglot {}
```

C: If Polyglot has multiple members which you all wan't to use you can import all members of Polyglot by writing

```
import * as Polyglot from '../../../node_modules/node-polyglot/build/polyglot.min.js';
```

D: Polyglot gets imported but not bind to any variable. But Polyglot exposes a global object which you don't have any access to until you declare the variable it will be available under.

See the [mdn reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) for better explanation

Depending on what build system you use there is no answer which one of the should always work but my solution A should work in every webpack build aswell as B and C. Friendly reminder that A and D are no optimal solutions and should only be used if there is no other way to import/use the module.

Edit:
The [ES6 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-source-text-module-records) just describes what a modules is, what it contains, how a module should be [exported](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-exports) and [imported](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-imports) and more on.

So there is no way how ES6 would handle these "old" modules since it isn't a library or anything like that. [CommonJS](http://www.commonjs.org/) is also just a standard, which is implemented by Node.js which module imports you know with `require('module')`.

So Webpack comes into your help which can handle both of these module systems, because they implemented both of these.

If you create an empty project and build with webpack via `webpack --env development`, you can see how webpack handles the different modules. Webpack compiles your code and ads it's own handling for ESModules or CommonJS Modules. Depending on what module they find they will call different Methods. I added an example with the compiled code.

```js
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/  // The module cache
/******/  var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/  // The require function
/******/  function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/   // Check if module is in cache
/******/   if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/    return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/   }
/******/   // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/   var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/    i: moduleId,
/******/    l: false,
/******/    exports: {}
/******/   };
/******/
/******/   // Execute the module function
/******/   modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/   // Flag the module as loaded
/******/   module.l = true;
/******/
/******/   // Return the exports of the module
/******/   return module.exports;
/******/  }
/******/
/******/
/******/  // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/  __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/  // expose the module cache
/******/  __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/  // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/  __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/   if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/    Object.defineProperty(exports, name, { enumerable: true, get: getter });
/******/   }
/******/  };
/******/
/******/  // define __esModule on exports
/******/  __webpack_require__.r = function(exports) {
/******/   if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/    Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/   }
/******/   Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/  };
/******/
/******/  // create a fake namespace object
/******/  // mode & 1: value is a module id, require it
/******/  // mode & 2: merge all properties of value into the ns
/******/  // mode & 4: return value when already ns object
/******/  // mode & 8|1: behave like require
/******/  __webpack_require__.t = function(value, mode) {
/******/   if(mode & 1) value = __webpack_require__(value);
/******/   if(mode & 8) return value;
/******/   if((mode & 4) && typeof value === 'object' && value && value.__esModule) return value;
/******/   var ns = Object.create(null);
/******/   __webpack_require__.r(ns);
/******/   Object.defineProperty(ns, 'default', { enumerable: true, value: value });
/******/   if(mode & 2 && typeof value != 'string') for(var key in value) __webpack_require__.d(ns, key, function(key) { return value[key]; }.bind(null, key));
/******/   return ns;
/******/  };
/******/
/******/  // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/  __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/   var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/    function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/    function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/   __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/   return getter;
/******/  };
/******/
/******/  // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/  __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/  // __webpack_public_path__
/******/  __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/
/******/  // Load entry module and return exports
/******/  return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = "./main.js");
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ({

/***/ "./esmodule.js":
/*!*********************!*\
  !*** ./esmodule.js ***!
  \*********************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
eval("\n\nObject.defineProperty(exports, \"__esModule\", {\n  value: true\n});\nexports.default = void 0;\n\nfunction _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError(\"Cannot call a class as a function\"); } }\n\nvar MyClass = function MyClass() {\n  _classCallCheck(this, MyClass);\n\n  console.log('test');\n};\n\nexports.default = MyClass;\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./esmodule.js?");

/***/ }),

/***/ "./main.js":
/*!*****************!*\
  !*** ./main.js ***!
  \*****************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
eval("\n\nvar test = _interopRequireWildcard(__webpack_require__(/*! ./esmodule.js */ \"./esmodule.js\"));\n\nfunction _interopRequireWildcard(obj) { if (obj && obj.__esModule) { return obj; } else { var newObj = {}; if (obj != null) { for (var key in obj) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) { var desc = Object.defineProperty && Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor ? Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, key) : {}; if (desc.get || desc.set) { Object.defineProperty(newObj, key, desc); } else { newObj[key] = obj[key]; } } } } newObj.default = obj; return newObj; } }\n\n__webpack_require__(/*! ./module */ \"./module.js\");\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./main.js?");

/***/ }),

/***/ "./module.js":
/*!*******************!*\
  !*** ./module.js ***!
  \*******************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
eval("\n\nmodule.exports = {\n  myFunction: function myFunction() {\n    console.log('Test');\n  }\n};\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./module.js?");

/***/ })

/******/ });

//// main.js
require('./module')
import * as test from './esmodule.js';
//// esmodule.js
export default class MyClass{
    constructor(){
        console.log('test')
    }
}
//// module.js
module.exports = {
    myFunction: function () {
        console.log('Test')
    }
}
```

You can see that Webpack creates a self executing function which gets all the created modules with their `{ id(pathToFile) : function(module, exports, __webpack_require__)`. In the 2 different module types (ESModule, Module --> CommonJS) you can see that Webpack handles the types differently. If you want a more in depth look i can edit my post again.

Comment: If you use `npm` and see what is inside polyglot.js (min) you will see that there is no `export class` inside - so why B and C works (in some projects) ?

Comment: if i install their package there is only a index.js inside the node-polyglot folder. Inside the file a module is exported (`module.exports = Polyglot`) in the last line. The ES6 imports can handle these "old" module exports.

Comment: the compiled code is in `/node_modules/node-polyglot/build/` (`polyglot.js` and its minified version:`polyglot.min.js`) - how ES6 handle these "old" module exports ?

Comment: I think the ES6 import syntax is based on the CommonJS and AMD module system. I think depending on what build tool you use they support all of these imports thats why you mostly can use all of them. EcmaScript itself is just standard which defines how modules should look like. Just like JavaScript is a implementation of EcmaScript its up to the browsers/build tools what they implement and support.

Comment: I'm partially satisfy with this answer - still is unknow how ES6 handle these "old" module exports (you only gave your suppositions). You will get the bounty, however I will not check this question as accepted unless you develop your answer in this point.

Comment: I'll research the official docs and edit my answer, but as i can say ES6 doesn't do anything because it's just a definition how modules should look like and how they should be handled.

Comment: If you can give more depth info it will be nice

Comment: The only thing i can do more, is explaining how the webpack code works if that is what you are looking for

Comment: Do you try to use  `polyglot.min.js` in webpack in A,B,C,D ways and compare the results?

Comment: If you provide me the correct package name and version i can do that. I tried `npm i node-polyglot@2.3.0` (current version) and there is no min version in that package

Comment: I use this: `"node-polyglot": "2.2.2"` in my recent project