# Bootstrap modal is not shown on angular 8 on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am trying to display a modal on a button click in an angular application. I installed bootstrap and wrote the code specified in the bootstrap tutorial. The modal is available on click as its available during inspecting the html of browser but not showing on the browser. However changing the modal elements display property from block to contents displays the modal.  Please find the current code below.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                      Launch demo modal
                    </button>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The modal is being displayed in normal html and css not in angular

Comment: dose this is answer of youe question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400811/how-to-use-code-to-open-a-modal-in-angular-2/42597422  ?

Comment: Its for a hidden button right, in my case when i click the button the modal is rendered to the DOM but not displayed

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try with below code

IN your HTML file

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" (click)="openModal()">click to open</button>
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  [ngStyle]="{'display':display}">
         <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
               <div class="modal-content">
                     <div class="modal-header">
                           <h4 class="modal-title">Model Title</h4>
                           <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="onCloseHandled()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                         </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                           <p>Model body text</p>
                         </div>
                     <div class="modal-footer">
                           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="onCloseHandled()" >Close</button>
                         </div>
            </div>
             </div>
 </div>
```

In your TS(component) file

create 2 method

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styles:[
    `.modal{background: rgba(0,0,0, .5);`
  ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
display = "none";
  ngOnInit() {
   }
openModal() {
    this.display = "block";
  }
  onCloseHandled() {
    this.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you

let me know if you have any query

thanks

Comment: can the back drop  get blurred on the modal load?

Comment: yes you can just put this in style `.modal{background: rgba(0,0,0, .5);`

Comment: hii please look above answer I have made change replace it with your html and ts and let me know if it not work thanks for updating..

Comment: Yes i already did update with the code bro, but its not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205371/discussion-between-v5nxt-and-kushal-shah).

Comment: thank you so much! this answer helped me alot.

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below in your index.html file -> within the body section.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Override the following class

```
.fade.modal {
   opacity: unset !important;
}
```