# Call jquery file from angular2

Tags: jquery, typescript, angular

I need to add a file already created with jquery in my typescript

for example a file that add effect and animations to html
(i have already jquery installed)

```
declare var jQuery:JQueryStatic;

 $("#id").nameOfMyclassOfjQuery({   });
```

for example I need to integrate a template that create a gridmanager to run this directly in index.html I need to call like this (after I added grid.js into my index.html)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#id").grid({ );
 });
```

but if I'm inside a component.ts how to call this ?? when I put this the word grid is not known by jquery `$("#id").grid({ );`

Comment: What do you mean with file?

Comment: grid is not a standard function in jQuery. What file did you previously include to make this available? Or which jQuery grid are you using?

Comment: I'm using gridmanager   https://github.com/neokoenig/jQuery-gridmanager

Answer (score 0):

There are bunch of questions and answers here. For example [Replace draggable function in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35997969/replace-draggable-function-in-angular-2/37007700#37007700)

Same applies to your `grid`

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem I added just this

```
interface JQuery {
    gridmanager: any;
}
```

and I added the gridmanager.js and css files to my project

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call any jquery code in Angular 2 components call them in ngOnInit method.
For instance I was using Materialize CSS with Angular 2 and various components of Materialize required initialisation with jQuery, so this is what I did:-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var jQuery: any;
class SampleClass implements OnInit{
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
         //Your jQuery code here
    }
}
```