# Integrate Select2 into the Angular2 app

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, jquery-select2

I'm trying to integrate `Select2` into the `Angular2` app I'm building. I managed to get `select2` running and my multiple selects are transformed as expected. My problem now is how am I supposed to get the selected values and which event should I use for the binding. I tried binding `(change)` event on the select element but nothing happened. Maybe I should use some other event on the created by the plugin `select2-container` element?
The `select2` plugin is integrated following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30662773) answer. 
Anybody tried similar mix? Is it possible to get it work or I have to switch to [ng2-select](http://valor-software.com/ng2-select/) directive instead?

**Update**
Bonus question :) - Even if I give up `select2` and use standard multiple select, how should I get its value? I tried binding it to a property with `[(ngModel)]="_selectedValues"` but it remains empty when I select any option. Is the multiple checkbox the only way for multiple choice?

**Update 2**
For the bonus question - the workaround I found was to use one way event binding like `(change)="selectedValues=$event.target.selectedOptions"`. Then I added a `setter` for the `selectedValues` property like this:

```js
public set selectedValues(value: Array<any>) {
    this._selectedValues.length = 0;
    for(let v of value){
        this._selectedValues.push(v.value);
    }
};
```

Comment: As for ng2-select, I've fount it to have too immature so far for it to useful for anything other than really basic use cases.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The only working solution for the `select2` I found, is getting the value with jQuery in the `ngAfterViewInit` method like this:

```
jQuery('.fields-select').on(
        'change',
        (e) => this._selectedValues = jQuery(e.target).val()
);
```

So my final code looks like this:

```
import {Component, AfterViewInit} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'filters',
    templateUrl: 'template.html'
})
export class FiltersComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    private _availableFields: Array<any> = ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3','Value4'];
    private _selectedFields: Array<string> = [];

    ngAfterViewInit(){
        jQuery('.fields-select').select2();
        jQuery('.fields-select').on(
            'change',
            (e) => this._selectedFields = jQuery(e.target).val()
        );
    };
}
```

And in the template:

```
<select id="fields" class="form-control fields-select" multiple="multiple">
    <option *ngFor="#field of _availableFields" [value]="field">{{field}}</option>
</select>
```

Hope this will save someone's life some day :)

Comment: how do you import the select2 and jquery at same time? I am having trouble with it

Comment: @Jonathan I just added them in the entry point of my app - in my case the index.html, like this:
`<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/select2/select2.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @RadoslavStoyanov Thanks for your answer. Any idea how to make jQuery select 2 compatible with Angular http and observable?

Comment: @RadoslavStoyanov In the latest version of Angular it should be <option *ngFor="**let** field of _availableFields" [value]="field">{{field}}</option>

Comment: @azakgaim Yeah, I know there are some differences between the versions of Angular, but the question and the answer were about Angular2, which used a syntax like this :) Thank you for the comment, though ;)

Comment: Solution is not working for me, it would be helpful if you share in https://plnkr.co

Answer (score 3):

I've made my own implementation of it, with options, value, and available items as Input params of my component. This is my first version of it, it could be very flexible and augmented pretty easily.

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, Output, AfterViewInit, EventEmitter, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'custom-select',
    template: `<select #select class="form-control"></select>`
})

export class CustomSelectComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('select') private select: ElementRef;
    @Input() items: any[];
    @Input() options: any = {};
    @Input() value: any;
    @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<string[]>();

    constructor() { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        let selectElement = $(this.select.nativeElement);

        if (this.isMultiple()) {
            selectElement.attr('multiple', true);
        }

        selectElement.select2({
            data: $.map(this.items, (obj: any) => {
                let item = {
                    id: this.options.identifier ?  obj[this.options.identifier] : obj.id,
                    text: this.options.name ? obj[this.options.name] : obj.name
                };

                if ($.trim(item.id) === '') { console.warn(`No 'id' value has been set for :`, obj); }
                if ($.trim(item.text) === '') { console.warn(`No 'name' value has been set for :`, obj); }

                return item;
            })
        });
        $(selectElement).val(this.value).trigger('change');

        selectElement.on('change', (e: any) => {
            this.valueChange.emit($(e.target).val());
        });

    };

    private isMultiple() {
        return !!(this.options && this.options.multiple === true);
    }
}
```

And you can call it like that

```
<custom-select [items]="array" [options]="{multiple:true}" (valueChange)="update($event)" [value]="valueVar"></custom-select>
```