# Select2 compatible with Angular2?

Tags: angular, jquery-select2

Do we have anywhere code or way to use select2 with angular2 ? When i tried to run the jquery selector way in on ngAfterViewInit then it does not handle this very well. Please suggest the way to implement in angular2

I have been doing it like this.

```
export class AppComponent{
   locations:any;
   ngAfterViewInit(){
     $('select').select2();
   }
   ngOnInit(){
   .....callToService(p=>this.locations=p);
   }
}
```

As locations are getting binded asynchronously so options are not reflecting.

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you have tried and what you try to accomplish.

Comment: Does this help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173678/angular2-and-select2 ?

Comment: hello Raphael no that didnt help as the options are changing. i mean dynamically loading. so to support all of those functionality is not working that way..

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i have done it please see it.