# Angular 2 - Directive with JQuery and Select2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have some `<select class='select'>`'s in a @Component.

I'm following a template which styles every select with a third-party library called Select2. The HTML + jQuery + Select2 code is:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.select').select2();
});
```

I was wondering if it would be a good idea to create a directive for doing this, so I tried:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[simple-dropdown]'
})
export class SimpleDropdownDirective {

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    $(el.nativeElement).select2();
  }

}
```

But I'm getting error on the `select2()` method. Since it's a third-party library I don't think I can install it as I've done with jQuery.

What would you suggest?

Comment: Have you seen any or all of http://stackoverflow.com/q/36173678/3001761, https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-select2, https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-select2

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes. Select2 was only an example of third party library. I'm facing the same issue with different libraries. I was wondering if I could import select2.js so I could make my Directive example work, as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/35055539/5922900 Look that dropdown function comes from 'semantic' library which was imported as well.

Comment: Inevitably *"how do I interface with any third party library"* is going to be too broad. If you could show the specific error you get in the current code that might help to solve this specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Select2 depends on jQuery, so this will not work out of the box.

When you use jQuery to select an element, you don't get a native Element, but the jQuery enhanced element.
You have the option to port Select2 to Angular 2 or get it to work with native browser APIs like querySelectorAll. (You can try to make a feature request to the author as well, but as Select2 states itself as jQuery dependant, I would not bet on getting it implemented.)

Comment: What I was trying to do is the same as what was done with semantic at:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/35055539/5922900 Look that dropdown function comes from 'semantic' library which was imported as well.