# How does angular 2 work with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I know that Angular 1 ran a subset of jQuery called jqlite. Does Angular 2 support an expanded subset? and moreover, does angular 2 still support direct-inject jQuery?

Comment: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/using-jquery-with-angular-2.0, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "support direct-inject jQuery". You can use jQuery with Angular but if you want to use features like WebWorker or serverside rendering you can't use jQuery with Angular.
Angular itself doesn't provide a subset of jQuery.

I think it's considered bad practice to use and direct DOM access in general should be avoided.

Comment: I suppose I meant referencing jQuery in the html using `<link/>` will pull in the full jQuery toolset into Angular.

Comment: That can be done. See the linke @echonax posted above.