# How to integrate bootstrap table into Angular 2?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-table

I want to integrate this 
[bootstrap table example](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) into a component. It doesn't work even though I attached source files to index.html, table works if it's inserted below root component in index. I have found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658564/cant-insert-a-bootstrap-table-inside-an-angular-2-component) but it's not solved, conversation somehow ends in this question? Thanks a lot for the answer I use this table code for my integration, [mytable](http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/30/)

```html
<table data-toggle="table"
       data-url="/gh/get/response.json/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/docs/data/data1/"
       data-click-to-select="true">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
        <th data-field="name">Name</th>
        <th data-field="stargazers_count">Stars</th>
        <th data-field="forks_count">Forks</th>
        <th data-field="description">Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: cmon, who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table data-toggle="table"
       data-url="/gh/get/response.json/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/docs/data/data1/"
       data-click-to-select="true">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
        <th data-field="name">Name</th>
        <th data-field="stargazers_count">Stars</th>
        <th data-field="forks_count">Forks</th>
        <th data-field="description">Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```