# Error get hold an element (tag in html) using typescript angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

I tried to use ElementRef and document and $('#ID') to get hold a div in my html it not work I tried in ngOnInit,ngAfterViewInit in my contructor also.

I tried by using @ViewChild

I have a problem with loading when I call for example $('#ID') i get undefined because after any interaction with the template it work

I need just to get hold a tag div from my html page

(I'm using the angular 2 rc1 can you help me to know a source of probleme) thanks

Comment: please add some code

Answer (score 1):

Briefly: "Angular way" tells you not to access DOM directly - this is slow and hard to maintain the code.

The way you can access the `div` depends on the purpose of access. If you want to update text inside your `div` you can use interpolation `{{ }}`:

```
<div> {{ text_value_from_model }} </div>
```

If you want to handle `click` on the `div`:

```
<div (click)="onClick()">Text</div>
```

Long version: my favorite article about using jQuery with Angular https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542

Also a very good answer about using jQuery in Angular2 https://stackoverflow.com/a/30662773/1267942