# Angular 2 Component Router - How to run View code

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm using the Component Router and the routing part works well. But I can't figure out how to run JS to modify the template once the template has loaded (and not before).

For example, I want to run:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    "use strict";
    $(".preloader").delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

But obviously this can't run until the preloader div is loaded.

What's the best practice for doing this? I fiddled around with OnInit but it felt weird putting UI modifying code in the controller...err...I mean, component.

Comment: The best practice is to avoid jQuery if you use Angular: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background/15012542#15012542

Comment: Sure, but in this case I'm using someone else's template so rewriting it without jquery would take a bit of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, try `css` animation.

Reference your `.preloader` using `ElementRef`:

```
constructor(private _el: ElementRef) {
   this.preloader = jQuery(this._el.nativeElement).find('.preloader');
}
```

More details here: [How to use jQuery with Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular2)

In `AfterViewInit` (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#afterview) do `setTimeout` for 350 ms and change class to something having `transition` (details https://stackoverflow.com/a/6943704/1267942)

**Update**: as of Angular 2 RC4 the Animation is in pretty good shape https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html (I haven't tried it yet)

Comment: Thank you. For anyone else having this issue, I went with the jquery reference from within AfterViewInit() for the time being.