# LightGallery is not working for angular 2

Tags: angular, lightgallery

I am using LightGallery to display user pictures. How use LightGallery in angular 2 ?.

Comment: here is how to use jquery with angular2 . . . follow the same approach.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular2

Answer (score 0):

1. Install jQuery Typings in project: tsd install jQuery
2. Load jQuery with script tag ( or other loaders... )
3. Wrap any jQuery plugin with Angular 2 Directive

Example:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[light-gallery]"
})
export class LightGallery{
  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    jQuery(el.nativeElement).lightGallery();
  }
}
```

Then use the above directive in your angular 2 components.