# Close bootstrap modal using typescript in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a button, on the click of which I am opening a bootstrap modal pop-up. The modal pop-up contains some field with a submit button. I want to close the pop-up only when I am done saving the data. I can't use data-dismiss as it will close the pop-up right after user hits the button. Is there a way to close the pop-up through typescript?

expense.component.html

```
<div id="AddExpense" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add Expense</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form id="form" (ngSubmit)="saveExpense();">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <table class="table table-responsive" style="border:0">
                                <tr *ngFor="#column of columnInputs" style="height:20px;">
                                    <td class="text-right" style="padding-top:10px;border:0">
                                        <h4> {{column.name | case}}: </h4>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-center" style="padding-top:10px;border:0">
                                        <input *ngIf="column.name != 'status'" type="{{column.name == 'created_Date' ? 'date' : 'text'}}" name="{{columns.name}}" required [(ngModel)]="column.value" class="form-control" />
                                        <select class="form-control" *ngIf="column.name == 'status'" [(ngModel)]="column.value" name="{{column.name}}" required>
                                            <option value="status">--Select--</option>
                                            <option value="1">Paid</option>
                                            <option value="2">Unpaid</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"> Add Expense </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think you'd be better off with an angular2 implementation of a modal. Have a look at this: https://github.com/pleerock/ng2-modal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng2-bootstrap show/hide modal as child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735858/ng2-bootstrap-show-hide-modal-as-child-component)

Answer (score 18):

you can use the action on close button

```
<div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" #closeAddExpenseModal>&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add Expense</h4>
            </div>
```

and in your controller you can add this line after the action you use

```
this.closeAddExpenseModal.nativeElement.click();
```

you will need to add this imports to your controller

```
import { ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
```

you will need also to define closeAddExpenseModal

```
@ViewChild('closeAddExpenseModal') closeAddExpenseModal: ElementRef;
```

Comment: I believe this should be the accepted answer as it demonstrates the solution the OP is seeking. Plus it is in my opinion the least invasive solution to this problem (i.e. it does not require mixing Typescript and Javascript).

Comment: For reference, if you wish to follow other, then below link may help full to you.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-close-bootstrap-modal?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thanks @Rao it works. And also thanks for example you shared.

Comment: @JoshStark any idea how to do this if the Close button is in one component and the modal is in another component?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Hitting the close button without any controller logic doesn't close the modal, so it's useless to simulate a click if that click doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

With your id="AddExpense", you can close the modal with the below code anywhere in your typescript.

`document.getElementById('AddExpense').click();` // where you want to dismiss your modal

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an `id` to the button and in the `.ts` file call it using `getElementById` selector and `setAttribute` of `'data-dismiss'` to `'modal'` and you can set this attribute after your API call or whatever functionality you wanna add.

Example:

```
close(){document.getElementById('abc').setAttribute('data-dismiss','modal');}
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure what you really need to do but If you want to close modal with typescript you can just give an id to your html modal and call 'hide' method.

```
$('#newPostModal').modal('hide');
```

Sorry if this isn't what you want maybe if you can explain me better I can help you

Comment: typescript doesn't recognize $ symbol

Comment: just import "declare var $: any;"

Comment: $ is a jquery selector. It can't be declared like a normal variable in typescript. Even if I do that it will not have same pointer functionality as jquery $

Comment: You can import jquery inside angular 2 and use all functions... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular2

Comment: this does hide `modal` but not change dark color of background appear with modal