# How to implement Modal Dialog in Angular 2 and above

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap

I am a newbie to angular.

I have used bootstrap modal using the package [ng2-bootstrap](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/).

My View file is

```
<div bsModal #lgModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Area Master</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" (click)="lgModal.hide();" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal Content here...

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to know how to show/hide this modal from the component (type script file).

Type script file is

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Area } from './area';
import { AreaService } from './area.service';
@Component({

  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-areas',
  templateUrl: './areas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./areas.component.css']
})

export class AreasComponent implements OnInit {
  area_form: FormGroup;
  new_area: Area;
  areas: Area[];
  @ViewChild('lgModal') lgModal:ElementRef;
  constructor(
    private areaService: AreaService,
    private router: Router,
    private form_builder: FormBuilder) { }

  getAreas(): void {
    this.areaService
      .getAreas()
      .then(areas => this.areas = areas);
  }

  submit(area: Area): void {
    console.log(area);
    this.areaService.create(area)
      .then(area => { this.areas.push(area) })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAreas();
    this.lgModal.show();
    this.area_form = this.form_builder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      pincode: ['', Validators.required],
      status: ['Active'],
      type: ['Busines Service Area']
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: from where you are launching the modal?

Comment: Was the answer helpful??

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your common child modal component will be as below

```
import {Component,Input, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'common-modal',
  template: `
   <div bsModal #childModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">{{title}}</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="hideChildModal()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <ng-content select=".modal-body"> </ng-content>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="hide()"> Cancel </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  `,
})
export class CommonModalComponent {
   @ViewChild('childModal') public childModal:ModalDirective;
   @Input() title:string;
  constructor() {
  }
  show(){
    this.childModal.show();
  }
  hide(){
    this.childModal.hide();
  }
}
```

Using the child component in your parent component will look as below

```
import {Component, ViewChild, NgModule,ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ModalDirective,ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import {CommonModalComponent} from './child.modal';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="childModal.show()">Open modal</button>
    <common-modal  #childModal [title]="'common modal'"> 
    <div class="modal-body">
    Hi heloo </div>
    </common-modal> 

  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('childModal') childModal :CommonModalComponent;
  constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
  }

}
```

Using the above code you can have a separate common modal dialog which can be reused, so that your header & footer remains the same and you can use **Content-Projection** to use change the body of the modal dialog.

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/t4JwdewzXXBrnQRV6QMe?p=preview)**

Comment: Playing with the plunker, it works if AppComponent @ViewChild is commented out, but not if the viewContainerRef is removed. What is viewContainerRef doing? there's no obvious usage of it in the code. This is the first time I've seen it mentioned in connection to ModalDirective.

Comment: @RichardMatsen do you need some help from me?

Comment: Cheers, looking at the plunker, could you say what ViewContainerRef injected into the AppComponent does? I'm using ng2-bootstrap v1.3.3 with import syntax   ModalModule.forRoot(), which provides ComponentLoaderFactory & PositioningService, but I can't figure out why you inject ViewContainerRef and if I need it with my version.

Comment: @Aravind.... can you please help me out with this query..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535102/deleting-selected-items-from-mat-list-not-working-in-angular-2-using-angular-mat/49541113#49541113

Answer (score 1):

The below answer is in reference to the latest [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples)

**Component Controller**

```
import { TemplateRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-app-registration',
  templateUrl: './app-registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-registration.component.css']
})

export class AppRegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('editModal') editModal : TemplateRef<any>; // Note: TemplateRef

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

  openModal(){
    this.modalService.open(this.editModal);
  }

}
```

**Component HTML**

```
<ng-template #editModal let-modal>

<div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Edit Form</h4>
  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss()">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
  <!-- YOUR FORM DATA -->
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close()">Save</button>
</div>

</ng-template>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...

    NgbModule

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now (v1.8.1+) you can do it easier by using modal service
you can use templates and components for creating modals
http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-section