# There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "bs-modal" when using ng2-bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, angular2-template, ng2-bootstrap

I am following the example given here https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/modals

But when i put the template in my html

```
<div class="modal fade" bsModal #staticModal="bs-modal" [config]="{backdrop: 'static'}"
     tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> 
.........
.......

</div>
```

i also have below entry in my app.module.ts

```
import { ModalModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ModalModule.forRoot(),...]
})
```

and below message shows up, i am not sure what i am missing

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "bs-modal" ("
</p-dialog>

<div class="modal fade" bsModal [ERROR ->]#staticModal="bs-modal" [config]="{backdrop: 'static'}"
     tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labell"): PreCheckComponent@80:32
Can't bind to 'config' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
</p-dialog>
```

according to guide i dont have to import anything to my component

Comment: Update your post with the component typescript file code

Comment: i just added some code, let me know if anything else you want me to add

Comment: checkout my answer. let me know if need any more help

Comment: actually i am unable to import ModalDirective, its giving me errors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must be missing the below line in your component

```
@ViewChild('staticModal') public staticModal:ModalDirective;
```

For more information on ng2-bootstrap modal you can see this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735858/how-to-show-hide-bootstrap-modal-from-a-component/42736058#42736058)** which contains the demo as well.

Answer (score 13):

You need to import ngx-bootstrap modal module on your module like below:

```
import { ModalModule } from "ngx-bootstrap";
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ModalModule.forRoot()
    ]
})
```

Comment: Import of ModalModule.forRoot() helped me.

Answer (score 5):

Just incase if you are on this thread because you are getting same error even if you have added following line to NgModule

```
ModalModule.forRoot()
```

Make sure your import is the correct one.

**Correct import**

```
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
```

**Wrong import**

```
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/public_api';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing ModalDirective.

```
@ViewChild('yourModal') public YourModal:ModalDirective;
```