# Angular 2: Set modal in component class

Tags: angular

in my Angular 2 app I have:
 **bla.component.html** and corresponding **bla.component.ts**.

In **bla.component.html** I have modal:

```
<div bsModal #myModal="bs-modal" ...></div>
```

I would like to set this **myModal** into **bla.component.ts**:

```
...
export class BlaComponent {
   public myModal: ModalDirective;
```

I am not sure how to do it.

(What I actually want to achieve is that I will be able to close modal from component class.)

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: myModal  is a directive or component?

Comment: myModal is directive

Comment: have a look at this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735858/ng2-bootstrap-show-hide-modal-as-child-component/42736058#42736058)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, just add **@ViewChild('myModal')** into component class:

```
...
export class BlaComponent {
   @ViewChild('myModal') public myModal: ModalDirective;
```