# Unknown HTML tag modal in angular2

Tags: angular, modal-window

I want to create custom modal window referring this link:-
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/01/24/angular-2-custom-modal-window-dialog-box

When i am using   it's showing unknown HTML tag and on console showing error, i.e.

Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'modal' is not a known element:
1. If 'modal' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'modal' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
    Open Modal 1

```
[ERROR ->]<modal id="custom-modal-1">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-body">
```

"): HeapMemoryGraphComponent@6:4 ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:
'modal' is not a known element:

Please guide,Thanks.

Comment: Is your modal code, i.e. the ts file with the selector: 'modal', registered in your app.module.ts file ? In your @NgModule declarations, after having imported the file ?

Comment: Refer this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735858/ng2-bootstrap-show-hide-modal-as-child-component/42736058#42736058)

Answer (score 0):

Put this component in declarations in the `app.module`

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
],
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ModalComponent <----
],
providers: [
    ModalService
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Hey Dmitrij, ModalComponent showing error inside declarations (Can not find name ModalComponent).

Comment: import { Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import {ModalService} from "./modal.service";


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id.toString(),
  selector: 'modal',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})

export class ModalComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() id: string;
  private element: JQuery;

  constructor(private modalService: ModalService, private el: ElementRef) {
    this.element = $(el.nativeElement);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let modal = this;