# Angular 2 Showing a dialog using ViewContainerRef and NgIf

Tags: angular

Lots of tutorials show how we can use ViewContainerRef to dynamically insert a component to implement widgets like a dialog pop-up. (eg. https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2016/07/19/building-angular-2-components-on-the-fly-a-dialog-box-example/)

I was wondering what are the benefits over just using an *ngIf ?
I could just:

```
<my-dialog-component *ngIf="someFlagControlledByAService"></my-dialog-component>
```

which could save many lines of code

Thanks a lot!

Comment: check this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735858/ng2-bootstrap-show-hide-modal-as-child-component/42736058#42736058)

Comment: That answer doesn't really answer my question... The answer provided can also be done in ngIf right? What are the benefits of using this answer's method?