# Open modal dialog in a function in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, modal-dialog

I have an angular 4 application and I want to open a modal dialog in a function.

So, I have my modal code that I can open when I click on a button :

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="test" (click)="open(addProjectForm)">test</button>
```

But I want to open the modal from a function in the `ngOnInit` of component.ts.

So, how can I open the modal inside a function and not with the click option ?

Comment: simply call open(addProjectForm) from ngOnInit.

Comment: But the button with `open(addProjectForm` is in modal.component.html and I want to call this in another component : timeline.component.ts. So, the name can't be find.

Comment: so basically what you want to say is that you want to call the function defined in one component from another component right?

Comment: Yes. I want to call the open of a modal in another component.

Comment: Have a look at this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735858/ng2-bootstrap-show-hide-modal-as-child-component/42736058#42736058)

Comment: Actually it does matter which kind of graphical library you use. Is it bootstrap or angular material. If it's angular, do you use "angular powered bootstrap" or "ngx-bootstrap" ?

Answer (score 2):

[Angular powered Bootstrap.](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) can help you here.

In your component you have to import `NgbModal` and inject it in your Component, using the constructor. You can use this service to open the modal.

```
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({ ... })
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal)
  { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public show()
  {
    this.modalService.open('text');
  }
}
```

This will open a modal, with message "text". But I guess that you may want to add a more complicated message. You can also put HTML inside your component's view, and use that.

```
<ng-template #wizard>
  text
</ng-template>
```

Next inside your method you can add a reference to that template

```
@ViewChild('wizard')
public wizardRef: TemplateRef<any>;  

public show()
{
  this.modalService.open(this.wizardRef);
}
```

Now the content of the `<ng-template #wizard>` will be shown inside the modal.

You can set more details using the `NgbModalOptions` object, and specify it when calling the `open(ref, options)` method.