# How can I use bootstrap modal, toasty, etc. In aspnet core with angular 2 project?

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, aspnetcoretemplatepack

I am using Angular2 in my existing ASP.NET Core MVC project. I am already using toasty, modals and other libraries in my MVC `.cshtml` views.

However, I couldn't make those work in my components. Is there any example teaching how to use them.

Tried **ngModal** and others but could not make it work

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following post and update the question appropriately, by providing examples of what you have tried and errors you are getting:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have a look at this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735858/ng2-bootstrap-show-hide-modal-as-child-component/42736058#42736058)

Comment: @gardfbradaz thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's lots of providers who offer Modals , Pagination and other controls

Try this
http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals

It's the easyest to use as I know

Comment: this must be a comment

Comment: I can't comment , the 50 points reputation problem  , anyway he wanted an answer , should I copy a modal sample from some link ?

Answer (score 0):

this may help you, I use it in my own project.
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home