# Pass data from a component to a modal dialog in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, components

I have an angular 4 application and I have 2 components a timeline and a modal dialog. When I double click on the timeline I want to open the modal dialog with the datas passed into the double click function.

So, in the timeline.component.ts, I have :

```
        Timeline.prototype.onTaskDoubleClick = function(task){
            console.log("Double click on task" + task.id);
            console.log(task);
            $('#addProjectForm').click();
        }
```

How can I do to pass the object 'task' from this function to the modal component ?

Comment: Check this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735858/ng2-bootstrap-show-hide-modal-as-child-component/42736058#42736058)

Comment: Could you provide the call to the modal dialog? (in your component)

Comment: I click on a hidden button which is : `<button class="btn btn-primary" id="addProjectForm" (click)="open(addProjectForm)" style="display: none">test</button>
`

Comment: @Adrien did you look at my answer?

Comment: Yes, but I don't really understand it

Comment: I have used an `@Input` property called `title` to pass the data to the modal. which you should be using to pass your data.

Comment: For which is used  @ViewChild ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Input` and `@Output` for the flow.

Create a component `container`, and two other containers timeline and modal

inject both timeline and modal in the container component.

Now on click in Timeline component use the following

```
clickEmitter = new EventEmitter<task: any>()

doubleClick(task: any) {
  this.clickEmitter.emit(task);
}
```

Now bind this output to the container component as follows

```
<timeline  (clickEmitter)="clickHandler($event)"></timeline>
<modal [task]="modalInput"></modal>
```

Now the task container can get this from the conatiner as follows.

#### In Container Component

```
modalInput: any;

clickHandler(task) {
  this.modalInput = task;
}
```

Now, this can be recieved by Modal component as follows,

```
@Input
task
```

Comment: In this : "Timeline.prototype.onTaskDoubleClick = function(task){
            console.log("Double click sur la tache " + task.id);
            console.log(task);
            var clickEmitter = new EventEmitter();
             this.clickEmitter.emit(task);
        }" I got the error "Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined"

Comment: u need to change the method structure to angular version. No need to add method to the prototype, just call this method as plain angular click method.

Comment: But I use an external library for the timeline and I want to show the modal dialog when I double click on the timeline. So, I need to do like this to catch the event.