# Arbitrary location Component rendering in Angular 4 / Force ViewChild detection

Tags: angular, mapbox, mapbox-gl

My Angular 4 application uses a 3rd party Library (mapbox) to render content on a page. That library has a popup dialog feature that allows for popups to be displayed when a user clicks a pin on the map:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup-on-click/

The popup is called with something like the following code:

```
 map.on('click', 'places', function (e) {
    new mapboxgl.Popup()
        .setLngLat(e.features[0].geometry.coordinates)
        .setHTML('<div>this is a popup</div>')
        .addTo(map);
});
```

I want to render an Angular 4+ component into the popup div. Things I've tried:

**1) Binding a @ViewChild to that popup's div.**

```
// in the component that holds the map component 
@ViewChild("pop", { read: ViewContainerRef }) childContainer: ViewContainerRef;

//when the user clicks the popup
popup.setHTML("<div #pop></div>")
```

The `childContainer` is never assigned. I've tried waiting seconds after the popup is open, or calling `detectChanges()` on my component's `ChangeDetectorRef`. I've tried opening the popup in an `NgZone.runOutsideAngular()` and then running `detectChanges()` manually.

If I manually add the div to my html template, the popup renders as expected to that div's location.

**2) Rendering it using a factory to a div with that ID**

```
//when the user clicks the popup
popup.setHTML("<div id="pop">HERE</div>")

const element = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector("#pop"); //this is found
const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(PopupComponent);
const component = factory.create(this.viewContainerRef.injector, null, element);
```

The contents of the div HERE are replaced with `<!---->`. Clearly Angular is rendering *something* to that location, but not the actual component. Do I need a different injector?

**3) Placing the component render element directly into the popup:**

```
popup.setHTML("<popup-component></popup-component>")
```

It never turns itself into an actual component. Even with things like `detectChanges()` or `NgZone` runs.

**4) Any other ideas? How do I render an Angular component to an arbitrary html location defined outside of Angular?**

Comment: can you  create a plunker. I believe your complicating this can be easily achieved. Example for [**child modal with ViewChild**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735858/ng2-bootstrap-show-hide-modal-as-child-component/42736058#42736058)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this using a standard `.append` call. I don't love this solution, but it does appear to work and not have too many downsides, so I'm posting it here in case other folks find this question.

Add a hidden component to the same page as your map:

```
//map.component.html
<div id="map"></div>
<div style="display:none">
    <info-popup #infopop [id]="selectedId" [renderTo]="popupLocation"></info-popup>       
</div>
```

Bind the clicked popup by ID to a class property passed to the info-pop component above

```
//map.component.ts   
popupLocation: any;
selectedId: any;
initializeMap(): void {
  this.map.on("click", "pinLayer", (e: MapMouseFeaturesEvent) => {
     this.selectedId = e.features[0].properties["id"]; // assumes a distinct id per pin
     new mapboxgl.Popup({ closeButton: false })
            .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
            .setHTML("<div id='popupLocation'></div>")
            .addTo(this.map);
     this.popupLocation = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector("#popupLocation);
  });
}
```

Use that component with append:

```
//infopop.component.ts
export class InfoPopupComponent implements OnChanges {

    @Input() id: string;
    @Input() renderTo: any;
 constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }


    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        if ("id" in changes) {
            // load popup specific details and render
        }
        if (this.renderTo) {
            this.renderTo.append(this.elementRef.nativeElement);
        }
    }
}
```

This worked with bound [click] events on the infopop.component.html passing through correctly.

Comment: Can you please elaborate `load popup specific details and render`, I am really struggling here. Component loaded only the first time, and stop working after that