# Angular Material viewchild dialog without dialog component class

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, angular-material, angular-material2, angular5

Is there way that I can open an angular material 2 dialog with view child reference without creating a dialog component?

Comment: can you elaborate the question

Comment: like in ngx-bootstrap modal, Is there a way to open angular material 2 dialog with template reference in html. like this without creating component class for the dialog. use dialog just in html template of another component , https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-template

Comment: you can use which one is comfortable for you and supports your need. But to make the modal a reusable one I will suggest you to go with the child component

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you provide me a simple example to load dialog without using component class and inside a component view? like in the ngx-bootstrap template modal?

Comment: Refer this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735858/how-to-implement-modal-dialog-in-angular-2-and-above/42736058#42736058)

Comment: I am using Angular Material 2. Not ngx-bootstrap

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this

View.html

```
 <button (click)="openModal(mytemplate)">Open my template</button>

 <ng-template #mytemplate>
      <h1>It works</h1>
 </ng-template>
```

component.ts

```
 import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';

 export class Component implements OnInit {
      constructor(
           public dialog: MatDialog
      ) { }

      openModal(templateRef) {
           let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(templateRef, {
                width: '250px',
                // data: { name: this.name, animal: this.animal }
           });
    
           dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
               console.log('The dialog was closed');
               // this.animal = result;
           });
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. :D u saved the day!

Comment: thanks works perfectly