# How to make one option preselect in ng-select using angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-select

I had add popup field, when the popup opens i want to get one field to be preselected with its option, i am getting the required value in console but 
its not reflecting on html. Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="showlabel">Role</label>
   {{selectedRole}}
  <ng-select [options]="roles" [(ngModel)]="user.user.role_id" name="AddRole" class='filterDropDown cat' placeholder="Role" notFoundMsg="No Role Found" required> 
  </ng-select>
</div>
```

TS:
To open popup

```
addCompany (){ 
  this.user = new Users(); 
  this.addCompanies.show();
  let userData = this.roles.filter(role => role.label === 'appUser');
  if(userData && userData[0]) { 
    this.selectedRole = userData[0].label.toString();
  }
  console.log(this.selectedRole);
}
```

Comment: can you create a working example?

Comment: ya i will try to create a plunker

Comment: You can set the value of [(ngModel)]="user.user.role_id" in ngOnInit event

Comment: @Arun: can you please tell how? You mean this.user.user.role_id = "appuser" in ngOninit? i tried but didnt work

Comment: please create example  will check it

Comment: @Aravind
I am not getting how to create plunker with modal popup's. so is it possible to guide me with codes, i will give you inputs how u ask

Comment: Please use the modal from this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735858/how-to-implement-modal-dialog-in-angular-2-and-above/42736058#42736058)

Comment: @Aravind this is plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/sl9nPssqqRgENDRwe8xr?p=preview   facing some error il try to solve that in plunker

Comment: it is not working! @Bhrungarajni

Comment: could you please check if your plunkr is working

Comment: ya, some error is coming, trying to solve. will update you soon

Comment: try on stackblitz

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav ya i will try

Comment: i am using "angular2-select": "^1.0.0-beta.3", so its not installing in stackblitz.. but will try and give you updated one

Comment: for me its getting installed

Comment: i am getting this error Can't find modules:
angular2-select/dist/select.component.css (@1.0.0-beta.3)
angular2-select/dist/select.component.html (@1.0.0-beta.3)
angular2-select/dist/select-dropdown.component.css (@1.0.0-beta.3)
angular2-select/dist/select-dropdown.component.html (@1.0.0-beta.3)

Comment: is it possible to try with other select npm packages

Comment: user.user.role_id=userData[0].id? (id o whatever)

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    // set the value of dropdown which u want to select
  }
}
```

when your component load it it will run both ngOninit and constructor so you can set the preselect value any one place.

if you want with example i need data.

Comment: ya same way i did but didnt work.. ya i will create plunker

Comment: no it didnt because i am getting roles from backend