# Close modal window from angular component

Tags: angular, sweetalert

I need to close my modal window from the angular component, after successfully recording;
but the code doesn't work for me;
how can I do?

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 10.16.3
OS: win32 x64
```

--exp.component.html

```
  <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="modalExperience" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myExtraLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
```

--exp.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable, Inject, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

private element: any;
constructor(
    private el: ElementRef, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string
) {
    this.url = baseUrl;
    this.element = el.nativeElement;
}
Swal.fire({
    title: 'Great',
    html: res.mensaje,
    type: 'success'
}).then((result) = > {
    if (result.value) {
        //close modal -- it does not work
        this.element.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.classList.remove('modalExperience');
    }
});
```

With this code all the windows are closed, I see that it affects the selector of the component and the dark shadow of the modal remains.
Please tell me what is the right way!

Comment: Try using the  angular npm package for sweetalert, https://github.com/sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with a much earlier post right here on stackoverflow;
[Close bootstrap modal using typescript in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054728/close-bootstrap-modal-using-typescript-in-angular-2/39054934#39054934)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `.close()` method of sweetalert popup in order to close dialog. For example -

```
Swal.fire({
          title: 'Great',
          html: res.mensaje,
          type: 'success'
        }).then((result) => {
          if (result.value) {
            Swal.close();    // -->> This should work 
            this.element.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.classList.remove('modalExperience');
          }
        });
```

Comment: It's not about closing the Swal.fire alert;
I have a first window with a list of "work experiences" and an "add experience" button that opens a modal window.
After the confirmation of recording appears in a Swal.fire alert, there, in the component.ts is where I want to close the modal window.

Comment: Yes I got it, you can close any instance of swal alert by doing so in any component, I hope this clears more.

Comment: Hello
Thank you for your response, but as I say, it is not about closing the Swal.fire alert, that alert closes well.
it is about closing the window from typescript after confirming that it was added or edited correctly.
I hope you understand what I need.