# http://localhost:4200/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css 404 error in angular2

Tags: angular

I have added bootstrap dependencies in index.html file. this index file is in src folder. and node modules is in above it. Folder structure is given below.

```
Library
  node_modules
  src
    index.html
```

Now I am targeting to node_modules from index.html. My code is given below.

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And also tried with ./ and just starts from node_modules. What is the problem here.

Comment: Is the file for bootstrap there in the first place?

Comment: Its there in node_modules

Comment: If you have a `angular-cli.json` file, put the resource to bootstrap in there under `styles`

Comment: Its problem with jquery as well

Comment: Maybe try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39511788/how-to-import-jquery-to-angular2-typescrypt-projects

Comment: How can I call node_modules from index.html.. rather than giving cdn url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139123/discussion-between-edric-and-raj-m).

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

- Please check whether the file is available in under node_modules

  - import that CSS inside `styles.css` file, that will be compiled automatically

> Hope you are using `angular-cli` package

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```