# How to include dataTable to angular 2 application?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a simple application in angular 2. I want to display data in a paginated table. I found [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html) very nice and I would like to use in my app.

- The`html` of the example is in `home.component.html`,
- The `css` of the example is in script in `index.html` like:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.2/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
```

I want to know where I should put the java script code for this to work. I have tried to put in `index.html` and `home.compose.html`, but none on this worked correctly.

Please tell me where the java script code should go. 
Thank.
This is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        columnDefs: [ {
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets:   0
        } ],
        select: {
            style:    'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Seems to be a reasonable resource on this already [How to use jQuery with Angular2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular2)

Answer (score 4):

If you already took reference of Jquery in your Html page than no need to import it in component.ts file. See the below code it is working fine for me.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ModalComponent } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Global } from '../shared/global';
declare var $ : any;

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/Component/assignfeatureview.component.html'
})

export class AssignFeatureViewComponent {
    constructor() {

    }
    ngOnInit() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#tblAssignFeature').DataTable();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Angular compatible version of that, if still want to use them, if it's used in one Component, then just put the piece of code in `ngOnInt` in your component, also use import to import the code in your component, something like this:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {$} from "jquery";
//also import the datatables plugin for jQuery


@Component({
  selector: "app",
  templateUrl: "app.html",
  styleUrls: ["jquery.dataTables.min.css", "select.dataTables.min.css"]
});
export class LoginComponent {
  constructor() {     
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
    columnDefs: [ {
        orderable: false,
        className: 'select-checkbox',
        targets:   0
    } ],
    select: {
        style:    'os',
        selector: 'td:first-child'
    },
    order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
  });
  }

}
```

Comment: thank for your answer.  I am having this error : Module '"jquery"' has no exported member '$'

Comment: Depends how you install jQuery, Try this from this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39511788/how-to-import-jquery-to-angular2-typescrypt-projects : Step 1: get jquery in your project

npm install jquery
Step 2: add type for jquery

npm install -D @types/jquery
Step 3: Use it in your component!

import * as $ from 'jquery';
Ready to use $!

Answer (score 0):

```
 import {Component} from "@angular/core"; import {$} from "jquery";
    //also import the datatables plugin for jQuery


    @Component({   selector: "app",   templateUrl: "app.html",  
    styleUrls: ["jquery.dataTables.min.css",
    "select.dataTables.min.css"] }); export class LoginComponent {  
    constructor() {        }

      ngOnInit() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
        columnDefs: [ {
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets:   0
        } ],
        select: {
            style:    'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]   });   }

    }
```

Comment: sorry but I am having an error :  Module '"jquery"' has no exported member '$'

Comment: Add explanation with your code, talking about the problem.