# Make Webpack load files in specific order

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have an AngularJS project and I want Webpack to handle the build process for me, I need Webpack to output JS files dynamically from the `src` folder into my `HTML` template, and output them like this:

```html
<script src="source1.js"></script>
<script src="source2.js"></script>
<script src="source3.js"></script>
...
```

Is it possible to load files in specific order rather than getting them all in one big file?

Comment: Bundling code in such a way that dependencies are resolved correctly is a large part of the purpose of Webpack, so I’m wondering: what is the reason why you need to have separate files in order? Maybe there’s another way to achieve what you need.

Comment: @Aankhen I need to load some dependencies and also some modules should be loaded before some other modules

Comment: Can you specify your dependencies in your code itself using imports?

Comment: @Aankhen Sorry I didn't get what you mean, for example I have JQuery, Angular, some other AngularJs libs that I'm using all currently available in bower_components

Comment: It means that when you use JQuery in foo.js, for instance, you say `import $ from jquery;` at the top of the file. When Webpack compiles foo.js, it sees that you import JQuery, so it makes sure that JQuery is loaded before your code is. See https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/

Comment: More information about Angular, Webpack, and JQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39511788/how-to-import-jquery-to-angular2-typescript-projects