# Issues in rendering css/bootstrap classes in angular2

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I am having some issues in CSS/Bootstrap work when it is rendered in a angular2 component.

when I try to render the CSS/html contents in Index.html file (with proper references for CSS,JS) the application/functionality works fine. But when the same html contents along with CSS classes is rendered in the angular2 component, it doesn't work.

Based on the searches on internet I have done all these changes but nothing makes it working. I have added  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None for that component, still the CSS functionality doesn't work along with angular 2.

also the order of JS references file  are placed in the following order

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I have replicated the issue and checked into [Github url](https://github.com/snkrishnan1/Angular2AspNetCore)

can somebody help me with this issue?

Comment: css will work automatically, with out any additional configuration.
You just add the ref link on the index.html

If you need to include jsyou may go though my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is because we cant simply add js files in angular 2 by adding the ref link,
try this stack over flow solution

[How to use jQuery with Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular2)

**For Bootstrap you can use ng-bootstrap**
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-bootstrap