# Can not import jQuery with Typescript with Angular cli

Tags: jquery, npm, angular-cli, typescript2.0

I did:

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
```

Changed the angularcli.json to update the internal webpack configuration:

```
  "scripts": ["../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"],
```

Then I imported it into my component.ts

```
 import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Or

```
 import * as jquery from 'jquery';
```

Both did not help!

When I run this code:

```
  alert($("button")[0].innerText);
```

or any other code with the '$' variable.

Then I get this error during runtime:

```
error_handler.js:45EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8_jquery__.getJSON is not a functionErrorHandler.handleError
```

Why must it be so complicated? How can I fix that mess?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular2

Comment: That answer is before TypeScript 2.0 which I use. Things have changed.