# Angular2 and Gridstack.js issue: $(...).gridstack is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, gridstack

I am using Angular2 (2.3.1) and gridstack.js (gridstack.js 0.3.0) with jquery 1.11.1.  Tried following this example

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901473/wrap-gridstack-js-into-angular-2-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901473/wrap-gridstack-js-into-angular-2-component%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901473/wrap-gridstack-js-into-angular-2-component)

to get gridstack.js to work with Angular 2 and getting following errors:

> zone.js:170 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).gridstack is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (http://localhost:8080/:111:26)
>       at mightThrow (eval at webpackJsonp.87.module.exports (http://localhost:8080/scripts.bundle.js:88:9), :3583:29)
>       at process (eval at webpackJsonp.87.module.exports (http://localhost:8080/scripts.bundle.js:88:9), :3651:12)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.bundle.js:16599:31)
>       at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.bundle.js:16398:47)
>       at ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.bundle.js:16652:38)
>       at data.args.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.bundle.js:17813:29)

Not sure how to go about fixing this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you need to add the .js files to angular-cli.json as well not just index.html.

Answer (score 1):

> $(...).gridstack is not a function

the jquery lib extended by gridstack is not the same jquery lib you use in angular component.