# trying to wrap gridstack.js into angular2 dynamic component service

Tags: angular, dynamic, service

I am following this example:

[Wrap gridstack.js into Angular 2 component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901473/wrap-gridstack-js-into-angular-2-component)

Can't seem to get the approach outlined by @Etchelon, Can someone provide a working sample code of dynamic component service, ie:

```
import { DynamicComponentService } from "./dynamic-component.service";
```

I have spent few days on this.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: what is *DynamicComponentService * ?

Comment: This is what I need to build.  Example provided with @Etchelon is missing this part.  This is a service that creates dynamic component.  Not sure inner workings of this service and dynamic component.  Thus this question.