# How to use gridstack.js with Angular6 Project

Tags: angular, gridstack

I am working on a Angular6 Project and I need to use gridstack.js, how should I use it in this version of project

I have checked libraries like gridster but they don't support nesting functionality.

I need the same functionality as being provided by gridstack with nesting support as well.Need help?

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE: As of this week (29 Nov 2020), Gridstack is now jQuery-free!**

Gridstack still (as of March 2020) uses jQuery, which as it manipulates the DOM directly goes against the declarative approach of Angular.
As [@Adrian points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55487870/1667410), while not impossible to achiveve, it may be worth avoiding until others are complete work on [dropping jQuery from Gridstack](https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/issues/1084).

In the meantime there are other non-jQuery [packages that achieve the same goal](https://www.npmtrends.com/angular-gridster2-vs-angular2gridster-vs-angular2-dashboard-grid):

- Angular Gridster2 is popular: https://github.com/tiberiuzuld/angular-gridster2
- Angular2Gridster is also well maintained: https://github.com/swiety85/angular2gridster
- Angular2 Dashboard Grid unmaintained: https://github.com/drxwat/angular2-dashboard-grid

There may be others using Gridster2 that I have not come across, but you can check out a range of approaches here: https://angularscript.com/category/layout/

Comment: FYI it seems like work is complete on issue mentioned above and v3 is released... :)

Comment: Thanks @Micko - Please mark this answer as useful anyhows!

Comment: make sure to include `import 'gridstack/dist/h5/gridstack-dd-native';` in Angular project as described [here](https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/#include)

Answer (score 0):

Don't, gridstack is a jQuery plugin and including jQuery in an Angular project is breaking rule number one.

Comment: so how can we achieve the gridstack functionality in an angular project

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901473/wrap-gridstack-js-into-angular-2-component?rq=1

Comment: I have tried all of these suggestion over there, they didn't work for my angular6 project

Comment: Hi all - see my above answer and Micko's update :)