# tsd install and tsd query commands returning " zero results " message

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-material, typescript-typings

When i'm running any of these commands in git bash windows

> tsd query angular-material
>
> tsd query angular
>
> tsd install angular angular-material

every time i'm getting this message " >> zero results "

Comment: "tsd" is retired and replaced by "typings" https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings

Answer (score 19):

`tsd` is deprecated ([you can see it here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd)). The following steps helped me install the type definitions.

In the application folder

1. Delete typings folder (if it exists)
2. Run the following commands

   `npm init`

   `npm install --save @types/angular`

   `npm install --save @types/jquery`

   `npm install --save @types/lodash`

Comment: Hello Nikhil, how could I use jquery script in ngAfterViewInit hook? TIA

Comment: If you are looking for intellisense this is the way : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40355691/2847061

Comment: Otherwise just add the jquery script to index.html and declare $ as any in you component class. Check this plunker :
https://embed.plnkr.co/3nRhMXdRNmgduuKSd6fv/

Comment: Awesome, that worked. Thanks @Nikhil !(the first one)

Answer (score 12):

I'm new to type script and I'm having the same issue as you are having now. It seems tsd is out dated and you need to use typings.

```
npm install typings --global
```

It seems tsd is out dated and you need to use typings.

```
typings install dt~angular --global
```

Comment: typings is deprecated too. Use the solution by Nikhil Nambiar - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42977233/85963

Answer (score 1):

replace the code with 
npm install --save @types/angular
or 
npm install --save @types/jquery
or 
npm install --save @types/angular-material

Thats it... Yor are done..!

Comment: This is a duplicate answer and not even formatted as well as the existing answer.