# Including jQuery UI in Angular2 + WebPack + Yarn

Tags: jquery-ui, angular, webpack

How can I include jQuery UI in an Angular2 application?

The dependencies are managed by WebPack. So I added jquery-ui with `npm install --save jquery`, then `yarn`.

When I try to use jQuery UI's feature, $(...).tabs("show") as described in [jQuery UI example](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default), what I get is

```
vendor.js:104458 TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function
```

I looked at `vendor.ts` and wanted to try adding it there, but I didn't find a file which looked like the one to `require()`.

What are all the necessary steps to get `$(...).tabs()` (and jQuery UI functions in general) working?

Note for duplicaters: jQuery is not jQuery UI. jQuery UI is a plugin which adds functions to jQuery. I know how to import jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use jQuery with Angular2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular2)

Comment: jQuery is not jQuery UI. Not a duplicate.